# ajax PHP progress bar

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, progress-bar

I have a code that gets some data and send it to a php page that makes the process and finally shows the result of this process without reload the page:

So, I hace this code that calls process.php file.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btEnviar").click(function (){
      var datos = $("#formulario").serialize();
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST", 
      url: "process.php",
     data: datos, 
     contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", 
    beforeSend: function() {
    $("#status").html("Enviando...."); 
     },
   dataType: "html",
      success: function(datos){ 
    if(datos == 1){ 
     $("#status").html("Script procesado satisfactoriamente"); 
    }else if(datos == 0){ 
     $("#status").html("Error al procesar script"); 
    }
    }
    });
    });
    });
```

It is possible to make a progress bar of process.php ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: *"Is it possible"* Yes, it is possible. however, it will probably be more involved than you are willing to get into if you want the progressbar to actually display how far along in the process process.php is (It's definitely more involved than i would get into, i'd instead make process.php return sooner.) You would be better off just showing a spinning graphic.

Comment: it is possible, but dont

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php

Note, it doesn't work in fastCGI mode

Answer (score 0):

You may use some ready-made solution like [Reload Progress Bar](http://codecanyon.net/item/reloadprogressbar-jquery-plugin/5392218). However, check this post first [File upload progress bar with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery). I hope it helps.