# File upload progress bar with jQuery

Tags: jquery, file-upload, progress-bar

I am trying to implement an AJAX file upload feature in my project. I am using jQuery for this; my code submits the data using AJAX. I also want to implement a file upload progress bar. How can I do this? Is there any way to calculate how much has already been uploaded so that I can calculate the percentage uploaded and create a progress bar?

Comment: Have you looked at the jQuery plugins or the jQuery UI? http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: Have you seen the examples on the [plugin homepage](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload)?

Comment: Check out the jQuery plugin [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery

Answer (score 147, accepted):

**Note:** This question is related to the [jQuery form plugin](http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload). If you are searching for a pure jQuery solution, [start here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery). 
There is no overall jQuery solution for all browser. So you have to use a plugin. I am using [dropzone.js](http://www.dropzonejs.com/), which have an easy fallback for older browsers. Which plugin you prefer depends on your needs. There are a lot of good comparing post out there.

From the [examples](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/):

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {

    var bar = $('.bar');
    var percent = $('.percent');
    var status = $('#status');

    $('form').ajaxForm({
        beforeSend: function() {
            status.empty();
            var percentVal = '0%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            bar.width(percentVal);
            percent.html(percentVal);
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            status.html(xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

**html:**

```
<form action="file-echo2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="myfile"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
</form>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="bar"></div >
    <div class="percent">0%</div >
</div>

<div id="status"></div>
```

you have to style the progressbar with css...

Comment: i used the 'uploadProgress' and used jquery-ui progressbar. thanks

Comment: Hello Jam,i implemented ur code but getting 500 internal server error.

Comment: Sound like you have an error in your PHP code. How does your file-echo2.php looks like?

Comment: This is probably with http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started but not directly with Jquery

Comment: @Lem: you're right, this code is from a demo using Form Plugin by malsup (http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress.html)

Comment: Misleading answer, it uses some jquery plugin, you should mention that!

Comment: @Pointer Null you are right. It is not clear, if you just read the answer. I edited my post.

Comment: what if multi upload?

Comment: I want to use a servlet as action. What will be the code in servlet?

Comment: Two of the three supporting links at the end are not websites any longer and one tried to get me to install a chrome extension.

Answer (score 353):

I've done this with jQuery only:

```
$.ajax({
  xhr: function() {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
        console.log(percentComplete);

        if (percentComplete === 100) {

        }

      }
    }, false);

    return xhr;
  },
  url: posturlfile,
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(fileuploaddata),
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: This is better in that it doesn't need jQuery.ajaxForm. Works perfect with just jQuery core library.

Comment: how to get `fileuploaddata` ?

Comment: This is entirely client sided. This shows the amount of data uploaded by the client, not what's received by the server. So, be sure to display the final 'success' message only after the end of the complete ajax request.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery This is about how to get `fileuploaddata`.

Comment: what is use jquery version? xhr working jquery 3.0.0?

Comment: If anyone wanted from Kathir's code to update an HTML progress bar then view my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/61130554/10029265

Answer (score 20):

I have used the following in my project.
you can try too.

```
ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.onreadystatechange = function () {

    if (ajax.status) {

        if (ajax.status == 200 && (ajax.readyState == 4)){
            //To do tasks if any, when upload is completed
        }
    }
}
ajax.upload.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {

    var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
    //**percent** variable can be used for modifying the length of your progress bar.
    console.log(percent);

});

ajax.open("POST", 'your file upload link', true);
ajax.send(formData);
//ajax.send is for uploading form data.
```

Answer (score 13):

check this out: http://hayageek.com/docs/jquery-upload-file.php
I've found it accidentally on the net.

Answer (score 10):

If you are using jquery on your project, and do not want to implement the upload mechanism from scratch, you can use https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload.

They have a very nice api with multiple file selection, drag&drop support, progress bar, validation and preview images, cross-domain support, chunked and resumable file uploads. And they have sample scripts for multiple server languages(node, php, python and go).

Demo url: https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/.

Comment: I have having trouble configuring that plugin with PHP. Do you know how?

Answer (score 10):

Here is a more complete looking jquery 1.11.x $.ajax() usage:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    function uploadProgressHandler(event) {
        $("#loaded_n_total").html("Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total);
        var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
        var progress = Math.round(percent);
        $("#uploadProgressBar").html(progress + " percent na ang progress");
        $("#uploadProgressBar").css("width", progress + "%");
        $("#status").html(progress + "% uploaded... please wait");
    }

    function loadHandler(event) {
        $("#status").html(event.target.responseText);
        $("#uploadProgressBar").css("width", "0%");
    }

    function errorHandler(event) {
        $("#status").html("Upload Failed");
    }

    function abortHandler(event) {
        $("#status").html("Upload Aborted");
    }

    $("#uploadFile").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var file = $("#fileUpload")[0].files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file1", file);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://testarea.local/UploadWithProgressBar1/file_upload_parser.php',
            method: 'POST',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            xhr: function () {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",
                    uploadProgressHandler,
                    false
                );
                xhr.addEventListener("load", loadHandler, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);

                return xhr;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i have try your code xhr: function()
                                        {
                                          var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                                          xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",
                                                                      uploadProgressHandler,
                                                                      false
                                                                     ); but not call my function in progress

Answer (score 7):

This solved my problem

```
var url = "http://localhost/tech1/index.php?route=app/upload/ajax"; 

$.ajax({
  xhr: function() {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
var $link = $('.'+ids);
          var $img = $link.find('i'); 
          $link.html('Uploading..('+percentComplete+'%)');
          $link.append($img);
      }
    }, false);

    return xhr;
  },
  url: url,
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(uploaddata),
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: Copy / paste of kathir's answer, basically

Answer (score 4):

[Kathir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22987941/10029265) is great as he solves that problem with just jQuery.
I just wanted to make some additions to his answer to work his code with a beautiful HTML progress bar:

```
$.ajax({
xhr: function() {
var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
  if (evt.lengthComputable) {
    var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
    percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);

    $('.progress-bar').width(percentComplete+'%');
    $('.progress-bar').html(percentComplete+'%');

  }
}, false);

return xhr;
},
url: posturlfile,
type: "POST",
data: JSON.stringify(fileuploaddata),
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
success: function(result) {
console.log(result);
}
});
```

Here is the HTML code of progress bar, I used Bootstrap 3 for the progress bar element:

```
<div class="progress" style="display:none;">
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped 
active" role="progressbar"
aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">
0%
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: progress event is not captured when file is being uploaded. Do you know the reason behind this?

Answer (score 1):

this is a simple way............

```
/* ajax progresss                 */
$(document).on('submit', '#sync', function () {
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: site_url + "sync/import_past_data",
data: {},
beforeSend: function(XMLHttpRequest)
{
    console.log('2');
  //Upload progress
  XMLHttpRequest.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
    if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
     var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
     $( ".jquery-uploadbar-selector" ).progressbar({ value: percentComplete }); //jquery progress bar for upload
    //incase you wanted an upload bar
   }
 }, false); 
 //Download progress
 XMLHttpRequest.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
   if (evt.lengthComputable) {  
     var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
     $( ".jquery-downloadbar-selector" ).progressbar({ value: percentComplete });
   //jquery progress bar for download or in other words The real answer for question
   }
 }, false); 
},
success: function(data){
  //Here goes the end of what you have done.. I would just type.. 
  console.log('1');
 }
});
});

/* end of progress                        */
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript:

```
<script>
/* jquery.form.min.js */
(function(e){"use strict";if(typeof define==="function"&&define.amd){define(["jquery"],e)}else{e(typeof jQuery!="undefined"?jQuery:window.Zepto)}})(function(e){"use strict";function r(t){var n=t.data;if(!t.isDefaultPrevented()){t.preventDefault();e(t.target).ajaxSubmit(n)}}function i(t){var n=t.target;var r=e(n);if(!r.is("[type=submit],[type=image]")){var i=r.closest("[type=submit]");if(i.length===0){return}n=i[0]}var s=this;s.clk=n;if(n.type=="image"){if(t.offsetX!==undefined){s.clk_x=t.offsetX;s.clk_y=t.offsetY}else if(typeof e.fn.offset=="function"){var o=r.offset();s.clk_x=t.pageX-o.left;s.clk_y=t.pageY-o.top}else{s.clk_x=t.pageX-n.offsetLeft;s.clk_y=t.pageY-n.offsetTop}}setTimeout(function(){s.clk=s.clk_x=s.clk_y=null},100)}function s(){if(!e.fn.ajaxSubmit.debug){return}var t="[jquery.form] "+Array.prototype.join.call(arguments,"");if(window.console&&window.console.log){window.console.log(t)}else if(window.opera&&window.opera.postError){window.opera.postError(t)}}var t={};t.fileapi=e("<input type='file'/>").get(0).files!==undefined;t.formdata=window.FormData!==undefined;var n=!!e.fn.prop;e.fn.attr2=function(){if(!n){return this.attr.apply(this,arguments)}var e=this.prop.apply(this,arguments);if(e&&e.jquery||typeof e==="string"){return e}return this.attr.apply(this,arguments)};e.fn.ajaxSubmit=function(r){function k(t){var n=e.param(t,r.traditional).split("&");var i=n.length;var s=[];var o,u;for(o=0;o<i;o++){n[o]=n[o].replace(/\+/g," ");u=n[o].split("=");s.push([decodeURIComponent(u[0]),decodeURIComponent(u[1])])}return s}function L(t){var n=new FormData;for(var s=0;s<t.length;s++){n.append(t[s].name,t[s].value)}if(r.extraData){var o=k(r.extraData);for(s=0;s<o.length;s++){if(o[s]){n.append(o[s][0],o[s][1])}}}r.data=null;var u=e.extend(true,{},e.ajaxSettings,r,{contentType:false,processData:false,cache:false,type:i||"POST"});if(r.uploadProgress){u.xhr=function(){var t=e.ajaxSettings.xhr();if(t.upload){t.upload.addEventListener("progress",function(e){var t=0;var n=e.loaded||e.position;var i=e.total;if(e.lengthComputable){t=Math.ceil(n/i*100)}r.uploadProgress(e,n,i,t)},false)}return t}}u.data=null;var a=u.beforeSend;u.beforeSend=function(e,t){if(r.formData){t.data=r.formData}else{t.data=n}if(a){a.call(this,e,t)}};return e.ajax(u)}function A(t){function T(e){var t=null;try{if(e.contentWindow){t=e.contentWindow.document}}catch(n){s("cannot get iframe.contentWindow document: "+n)}if(t){return t}try{t=e.contentDocument?e.contentDocument:e.document}catch(n){s("cannot get iframe.contentDocument: "+n);t=e.document}return t}function k(){function f(){try{var e=T(v).readyState;s("state = "+e);if(e&&e.toLowerCase()=="uninitialized"){setTimeout(f,50)}}catch(t){s("Server abort: ",t," (",t.name,")");_(x);if(w){clearTimeout(w)}w=undefined}}var t=a.attr2("target"),n=a.attr2("action"),r="multipart/form-data",u=a.attr("enctype")||a.attr("encoding")||r;o.setAttribute("target",p);if(!i||/post/i.test(i)){o.setAttribute("method","POST")}if(n!=l.url){o.setAttribute("action",l.url)}if(!l.skipEncodingOverride&&(!i||/post/i.test(i))){a.attr({encoding:"multipart/form-data",enctype:"multipart/form-data"})}if(l.timeout){w=setTimeout(function(){b=true;_(S)},l.timeout)}var c=[];try{if(l.extraData){for(var h in l.extraData){if(l.extraData.hasOwnProperty(h)){if(e.isPlainObject(l.extraData[h])&&l.extraData[h].hasOwnProperty("name")&&l.extraData[h].hasOwnProperty("value")){c.push(e('<input type="hidden" name="'+l.extraData[h].name+'">').val(l.extraData[h].value).appendTo(o)[0])}else{c.push(e('<input type="hidden" name="'+h+'">').val(l.extraData[h]).appendTo(o)[0])}}}}if(!l.iframeTarget){d.appendTo("body")}if(v.attachEvent){v.attachEvent("onload",_)}else{v.addEventListener("load",_,false)}setTimeout(f,15);try{o.submit()}catch(m){var g=document.createElement("form").submit;g.apply(o)}}finally{o.setAttribute("action",n);o.setAttribute("enctype",u);if(t){o.setAttribute("target",t)}else{a.removeAttr("target")}e(c).remove()}}function _(t){if(m.aborted||M){return}A=T(v);if(!A){s("cannot access response document");t=x}if(t===S&&m){m.abort("timeout");E.reject(m,"timeout");return}else if(t==x&&m){m.abort("server abort");E.reject(m,"error","server abort");return}if(!A||A.location.href==l.iframeSrc){if(!b){return}}if(v.detachEvent){v.detachEvent("onload",_)}else{v.removeEventListener("load",_,false)}var n="success",r;try{if(b){throw"timeout"}var i=l.dataType=="xml"||A.XMLDocument||e.isXMLDoc(A);s("isXml="+i);if(!i&&window.opera&&(A.body===null||!A.body.innerHTML)){if(--O){s("requeing onLoad callback, DOM not available");setTimeout(_,250);return}}var o=A.body?A.body:A.documentElement;m.responseText=o?o.innerHTML:null;m.responseXML=A.XMLDocument?A.XMLDocument:A;if(i){l.dataType="xml"}m.getResponseHeader=function(e){var t={"content-type":l.dataType};return t[e.toLowerCase()]};if(o){m.status=Number(o.getAttribute("status"))||m.status;m.statusText=o.getAttribute("statusText")||m.statusText}var u=(l.dataType||"").toLowerCase();var a=/(json|script|text)/.test(u);if(a||l.textarea){var f=A.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0];if(f){m.responseText=f.value;m.status=Number(f.getAttribute("status"))||m.status;m.statusText=f.getAttribute("statusText")||m.statusText}else if(a){var c=A.getElementsByTagName("pre")[0];var p=A.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];if(c){m.responseText=c.textContent?c.textContent:c.innerText}else if(p){m.responseText=p.textContent?p.textContent:p.innerText}}}else if(u=="xml"&&!m.responseXML&&m.responseText){m.responseXML=D(m.responseText)}try{L=H(m,u,l)}catch(g){n="parsererror";m.error=r=g||n}}catch(g){s("error caught: ",g);n="error";m.error=r=g||n}if(m.aborted){s("upload aborted");n=null}if(m.status){n=m.status>=200&&m.status<300||m.status===304?"success":"error"}if(n==="success"){if(l.success){l.success.call(l.context,L,"success",m)}E.resolve(m.responseText,"success",m);if(h){e.event.trigger("ajaxSuccess",[m,l])}}else if(n){if(r===undefined){r=m.statusText}if(l.error){l.error.call(l.context,m,n,r)}E.reject(m,"error",r);if(h){e.event.trigger("ajaxError",[m,l,r])}}if(h){e.event.trigger("ajaxComplete",[m,l])}if(h&&!--e.active){e.event.trigger("ajaxStop")}if(l.complete){l.complete.call(l.context,m,n)}M=true;if(l.timeout){clearTimeout(w)}setTimeout(function(){if(!l.iframeTarget){d.remove()}else{d.attr("src",l.iframeSrc)}m.responseXML=null},100)}var o=a[0],u,f,l,h,p,d,v,m,g,y,b,w;var E=e.Deferred();E.abort=function(e){m.abort(e)};if(t){for(f=0;f<c.length;f++){u=e(c[f]);if(n){u.prop("disabled",false)}else{u.removeAttr("disabled")}}}l=e.extend(true,{},e.ajaxSettings,r);l.context=l.context||l;p="jqFormIO"+(new Date).getTime();if(l.iframeTarget){d=e(l.iframeTarget);y=d.attr2("name");if(!y){d.attr2("name",p)}else{p=y}}else{d=e('<iframe name="'+p+'" src="'+l.iframeSrc+'" />');d.css({position:"absolute",top:"-1000px",left:"-1000px"})}v=d[0];m={aborted:0,responseText:null,responseXML:null,status:0,statusText:"n/a",getAllResponseHeaders:function(){},getResponseHeader:function(){},setRequestHeader:function(){},abort:function(t){var n=t==="timeout"?"timeout":"aborted";s("aborting upload... "+n);this.aborted=1;try{if(v.contentWindow.document.execCommand){v.contentWindow.document.execCommand("Stop")}}catch(r){}d.attr("src",l.iframeSrc);m.error=n;if(l.error){l.error.call(l.context,m,n,t)}if(h){e.event.trigger("ajaxError",[m,l,n])}if(l.complete){l.complete.call(l.context,m,n)}}};h=l.global;if(h&&0===e.active++){e.event.trigger("ajaxStart")}if(h){e.event.trigger("ajaxSend",[m,l])}if(l.beforeSend&&l.beforeSend.call(l.context,m,l)===false){if(l.global){e.active--}E.reject();return E}if(m.aborted){E.reject();return E}g=o.clk;if(g){y=g.name;if(y&&!g.disabled){l.extraData=l.extraData||{};l.extraData[y]=g.value;if(g.type=="image"){l.extraData[y+".x"]=o.clk_x;l.extraData[y+".y"]=o.clk_y}}}var S=1;var x=2;var N=e("meta[name=csrf-token]").attr("content");var C=e("meta[name=csrf-param]").attr("content");if(C&&N){l.extraData=l.extraData||{};l.extraData[C]=N}if(l.forceSync){k()}else{setTimeout(k,10)}var L,A,O=50,M;var D=e.parseXML||function(e,t){if(window.ActiveXObject){t=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");t.async="false";t.loadXML(e)}else{t=(new DOMParser).parseFromString(e,"text/xml")}return t&&t.documentElement&&t.documentElement.nodeName!="parsererror"?t:null};var P=e.parseJSON||function(e){return window["eval"]("("+e+")")};var H=function(t,n,r){var i=t.getResponseHeader("content-type")||"",s=n==="xml"||!n&&i.indexOf("xml")>=0,o=s?t.responseXML:t.responseText;if(s&&o.documentElement.nodeName==="parsererror"){if(e.error){e.error("parsererror")}}if(r&&r.dataFilter){o=r.dataFilter(o,n)}if(typeof o==="string"){if(n==="json"||!n&&i.indexOf("json")>=0){o=P(o)}else if(n==="script"||!n&&i.indexOf("javascript")>=0){e.globalEval(o)}}return o};return E}if(!this.length){s("ajaxSubmit: skipping submit process - no element selected");return this}var i,o,u,a=this;if(typeof r=="function"){r={success:r}}else if(r===undefined){r={}}i=r.type||this.attr2("method");o=r.url||this.attr2("action");u=typeof o==="string"?e.trim(o):"";u=u||window.location.href||"";if(u){u=(u.match(/^([^#]+)/)||[])[1]}r=e.extend(true,{url:u,success:e.ajaxSettings.success,type:i||e.ajaxSettings.type,iframeSrc:/^https/i.test(window.location.href||"")?"javascript:false":"about:blank"},r);var f={};this.trigger("form-pre-serialize",[this,r,f]);if(f.veto){s("ajaxSubmit: submit vetoed via form-pre-serialize trigger");return this}if(r.beforeSerialize&&r.beforeSerialize(this,r)===false){s("ajaxSubmit: submit aborted via beforeSerialize callback");return this}var l=r.traditional;if(l===undefined){l=e.ajaxSettings.traditional}var c=[];var h,p=this.formToArray(r.semantic,c);if(r.data){r.extraData=r.data;h=e.param(r.data,l)}if(r.beforeSubmit&&r.beforeSubmit(p,this,r)===false){s("ajaxSubmit: submit aborted via beforeSubmit callback");return this}this.trigger("form-submit-validate",[p,this,r,f]);if(f.veto){s("ajaxSubmit: submit vetoed via form-submit-validate trigger");return this}var d=e.param(p,l);if(h){d=d?d+"&"+h:h}if(r.type.toUpperCase()=="GET"){r.url+=(r.url.indexOf("?")>=0?"&":"?")+d;r.data=null}else{r.data=d}var v=[];if(r.resetForm){v.push(function(){a.resetForm()})}if(r.clearForm){v.push(function(){a.clearForm(r.includeHidden)})}if(!r.dataType&&r.target){var m=r.success||function(){};v.push(function(t){var n=r.replaceTarget?"replaceWith":"html";e(r.target)[n](t).each(m,arguments)})}else if(r.success){v.push(r.success)}r.success=function(e,t,n){var i=r.context||this;for(var s=0,o=v.length;s<o;s++){v[s].apply(i,[e,t,n||a,a])}};if(r.error){var g=r.error;r.error=function(e,t,n){var i=r.context||this;g.apply(i,[e,t,n,a])}}if(r.complete){var y=r.complete;r.complete=function(e,t){var n=r.context||this;y.apply(n,[e,t,a])}}var b=e("input[type=file]:enabled",this).filter(function(){return e(this).val()!==""});var w=b.length>0;var E="multipart/form-data";var S=a.attr("enctype")==E||a.attr("encoding")==E;var x=t.fileapi&&t.formdata;s("fileAPI :"+x);var T=(w||S)&&!x;var N;if(r.iframe!==false&&(r.iframe||T)){if(r.closeKeepAlive){e.get(r.closeKeepAlive,function(){N=A(p)})}else{N=A(p)}}else if((w||S)&&x){N=L(p)}else{N=e.ajax(r)}a.removeData("jqxhr").data("jqxhr",N);for(var C=0;C<c.length;C++){c[C]=null}this.trigger("form-submit-notify",[this,r]);return this};e.fn.ajaxForm=function(t){t=t||{};t.delegation=t.delegation&&e.isFunction(e.fn.on);if(!t.delegation&&this.length===0){var n={s:this.selector,c:this.context};if(!e.isReady&&n.s){s("DOM not ready, queuing ajaxForm");e(function(){e(n.s,n.c).ajaxForm(t)});return this}s("terminating; zero elements found by selector"+(e.isReady?"":" (DOM not ready)"));return this}if(t.delegation){e(document).off("submit.form-plugin",this.selector,r).off("click.form-plugin",this.selector,i).on("submit.form-plugin",this.selector,t,r).on("click.form-plugin",this.selector,t,i);return this}return this.ajaxFormUnbind().bind("submit.form-plugin",t,r).bind("click.form-plugin",t,i)};e.fn.ajaxFormUnbind=function(){return this.unbind("submit.form-plugin click.form-plugin")};e.fn.formToArray=function(n,r){var i=[];if(this.length===0){return i}var s=this[0];var o=this.attr("id");var u=n?s.getElementsByTagName("*"):s.elements;var a;if(u&&!/MSIE [678]/.test(navigator.userAgent)){u=e(u).get()}if(o){a=e(':input[form="'+o+'"]').get();if(a.length){u=(u||[]).concat(a)}}if(!u||!u.length){return i}var f,l,c,h,p,d,v;for(f=0,d=u.length;f<d;f++){p=u[f];c=p.name;if(!c||p.disabled){continue}if(n&&s.clk&&p.type=="image"){if(s.clk==p){i.push({name:c,value:e(p).val(),type:p.type});i.push({name:c+".x",value:s.clk_x},{name:c+".y",value:s.clk_y})}continue}h=e.fieldValue(p,true);if(h&&h.constructor==Array){if(r){r.push(p)}for(l=0,v=h.length;l<v;l++){i.push({name:c,value:h[l]})}}else if(t.fileapi&&p.type=="file"){if(r){r.push(p)}var m=p.files;if(m.length){for(l=0;l<m.length;l++){i.push({name:c,value:m[l],type:p.type})}}else{i.push({name:c,value:"",type:p.type})}}else if(h!==null&&typeof h!="undefined"){if(r){r.push(p)}i.push({name:c,value:h,type:p.type,required:p.required})}}if(!n&&s.clk){var g=e(s.clk),y=g[0];c=y.name;if(c&&!y.disabled&&y.type=="image"){i.push({name:c,value:g.val()});i.push({name:c+".x",value:s.clk_x},{name:c+".y",value:s.clk_y})}}return i};e.fn.formSerialize=function(t){return e.param(this.formToArray(t))};e.fn.fieldSerialize=function(t){var n=[];this.each(function(){var r=this.name;if(!r){return}var i=e.fieldValue(this,t);if(i&&i.constructor==Array){for(var s=0,o=i.length;s<o;s++){n.push({name:r,value:i[s]})}}else if(i!==null&&typeof i!="undefined"){n.push({name:this.name,value:i})}});return e.param(n)};e.fn.fieldValue=function(t){for(var n=[],r=0,i=this.length;r<i;r++){var s=this[r];var o=e.fieldValue(s,t);if(o===null||typeof o=="undefined"||o.constructor==Array&&!o.length){continue}if(o.constructor==Array){e.merge(n,o)}else{n.push(o)}}return n};e.fieldValue=function(t,n){var r=t.name,i=t.type,s=t.tagName.toLowerCase();if(n===undefined){n=true}if(n&&(!r||t.disabled||i=="reset"||i=="button"||(i=="checkbox"||i=="radio")&&!t.checked||(i=="submit"||i=="image")&&t.form&&t.form.clk!=t||s=="select"&&t.selectedIndex==-1)){return null}if(s=="select"){var o=t.selectedIndex;if(o<0){return null}var u=[],a=t.options;var f=i=="select-one";var l=f?o+1:a.length;for(var c=f?o:0;c<l;c++){var h=a[c];if(h.selected){var p=h.value;if(!p){p=h.attributes&&h.attributes.value&&!h.attributes.value.specified?h.text:h.value}if(f){return p}u.push(p)}}return u}return e(t).val()};e.fn.clearForm=function(t){return this.each(function(){e("input,select,textarea",this).clearFields(t)})};e.fn.clearFields=e.fn.clearInputs=function(t){var n=/^(?:color|date|datetime|email|month|number|password|range|search|tel|text|time|url|week)$/i;return this.each(function(){var r=this.type,i=this.tagName.toLowerCase();if(n.test(r)||i=="textarea"){this.value=""}else if(r=="checkbox"||r=="radio"){this.checked=false}else if(i=="select"){this.selectedIndex=-1}else if(r=="file"){if(/MSIE/.test(navigator.userAgent)){e(this).replaceWith(e(this).clone(true))}else{e(this).val("")}}else if(t){if(t===true&&/hidden/.test(r)||typeof t=="string"&&e(this).is(t)){this.value=""}}})};e.fn.resetForm=function(){return this.each(function(){if(typeof this.reset=="function"||typeof this.reset=="object"&&!this.reset.nodeType){this.reset()}})};e.fn.enable=function(e){if(e===undefined){e=true}return this.each(function(){this.disabled=!e})};e.fn.selected=function(t){if(t===undefined){t=true}return this.each(function(){var n=this.type;if(n=="checkbox"||n=="radio"){this.checked=t}else if(this.tagName.toLowerCase()=="option"){var r=e(this).parent("select");if(t&&r[0]&&r[0].type=="select-one"){r.find("option").selected(false)}this.selected=t}})};e.fn.ajaxSubmit.debug=false})
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#myform').on('change', '.wpcf7-file', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var myParent = $(this).parent();
                var filname= $('input[type=file]').val()

                if (filname) { 
                $(this).parent().find('#progress-div').show();          
                $('#myform').ajaxSubmit({
                    // target: '#progress-div123',/**********only for response************/
                    beforeSubmit: function () {
                        myParent.find('#progress-bar').width('0%');
                    },
                    uploadProgress: function (event, position, total, percentComplete) {
                        myParent.find('#progress-bar').width(percentComplete + '%');
                        myParent.find('#progress-bar').html('<div id="progress-status">' + percentComplete + ' %</div>')
                    },
                    success: function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {

                        //myParent.find('#progress-div').hide(10000);
                    },
                    resetForm: false
                });

                }
                return false;
            });


           /***********Error msg if file not valid***************/
                $('input[type=file]').change(function () {
                var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                var regex = new RegExp("(.*?)\.(pdf|txt|jpg|png|doc|docx|xlx|xls|xlsx|jpg|ppt|pptx|tif|tiff|\n\
                bmp|pcd|gif|bmp|zip|rar|odt|avi|ogg|m4a|mov|mp3|mp4|mpg|wav|wmv|stp|sldprt|sldasm|iges|igs|stl|x_t|step\n\
                |stp|prt|asm|idw|iam|ipt|dxf|dwg|pdf|slddrw|dwf)$");
                if (!(regex.test(val))) {
                    $(this).val('');
                    alert('Please select correct file format');
                }
                });
            /*********End*****************/

        });
</script>
```

Styles:

```
<style>
    body{width:610px;}
    #uploadForm {border-top:#F0F0F0 2px solid;background:#FAF8F8;padding:10px;}
    #uploadForm label {margin:2px; font-size:1em; font-weight:bold;}
    .demoInputBox{padding:5px; border:#F0F0F0 1px solid; border-radius:4px; background-color:#FFF;}
    #progress-bar {background-color: #12CC1A;height:20px;color: #FFFFFF;width:0%;-webkit-transition: width .3s;-moz-transition: width .3s;transition: width .3s;}
    .btnSubmit{background-color:#09f;border:0;padding:10px 40px;color:#FFF;border:#F0F0F0 1px solid; border-radius:4px;}
    #progress-div
    {
        border: 1px solid #0fa015;
        border-radius: 4px;
        margin: -35px 2px 7px 295px;
        padding: 5px 0;
        text-align: center;
        width: 277px;
    }

    #targetLayer{width:100%;text-align:center;}
</style>
```

Comment: This plugin (jQuery form) is quite old. ¿Does it still work with the current jQuery and Browsers?