# After I'm done with Ajax redirect the right window

Tags: jquery, forms

I was implementing my code from this answer to do Ajax calls in webkit on a form upload and it works well.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16200886/548558

My backend gives me a redirect if the form is valid but the redirect is happen in the iframe but I really want to have it the normal window. How I can do this? Anybody has an idea?

**CODE**

```
$(function() {
    $('#upload-form').submit(function() {
        // Prevent multiple submits
        if ($.data(this, 'submitted')) return false;
        $(this).prop("target", "file-upload");
        // Update progress bar
        function update_progress_info() {
            // $progress.show();
            $.getJSON(progress_url, {'X-Progress-ID': uuid}, function(data, status) {
                if (data) {
                    var progress = parseInt(data.uploaded) / parseInt(data.length);
                    var width = $progress.find('.progress-container').width()
                    var progress_width = width * progress;
                    $progress.find('.progress-bar').width(progress_width);
                    $progress.find('.progress-info').text('uploading ' + parseInt(progress*100) + '%');
                    console.log("progress")
                    console.log(progress)
                    window.setTimeout(update_progress_info, freq);
                }
            });
        };
        window.setTimeout(update_progress_info, freq);

        $.data(this, 'submitted', true); // mark form as submitted
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your call, if I understood your question, is made into an `iframe`, you must go to your `window` component, call to his parent (the container of this `iframe`) and call his methods `location` and `href`. I had to use this a few time ago and worked for me.

`window.parent.location.href = "/foo.html"`

Comment: If the form valid I get from my backend an redirect but this is happen in the iframe but I need it for the ajax calls. Where should I put it?

Comment: @Azd325 If you are recieving an `url` from your server, just add the code I posted into your success ajax function, replacing the value of `href` with the data you recieved from server. (i.e.) `...href = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: Ahh thansk, I'll try to do this. I will report.

Comment: but my ajax function is called multiple times to get the process of the upload. So I think it not possible to add it in the succes method

Comment: @Azd325 What? I don't understand what you meant. You have a form, with a submit button. When you press submit, you send a get request to your server. When your server sends the response, you should return a simple string, that will be parsed into Json format (something like `{"/foo.html"}`). When you recieve it in your success function into `data` parameter, the only thing you have to do is `window.parent.location.href = JSON.parse(data);`. Where is the problem/doubt? Correct me if you/your app are/is doing something different.

Comment: Sorry, but now I got what you said. I have to think how I will implement it because I have one view for the progress and one for the page(this does the redirect)

Comment: Thanks for help but I think I have to solve somewhere else because the  json response what you mention is also happen in the iframe. Maybe I check if the source location is changed of the iframe

Comment: Thanks I got it with this window.parent.location.href