# How to add file upload progress bar to Django website

Tags: python, django, file-upload, progress-bar

I am trying to use `django-progressbarupload app` to add progress bar to my Django app. But it is not working .... The `django-progressbarupload app` templates tags are loading fine and also file is uploading to the server but progress bar is not showing up ...and their is no javascript error on the console... I have followed this [tutorial](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-progressbarupload/0.1.5)

Can anyone tell how to add progress bar to Django app

Comment: do you have any error messages ? from your explanation i'm afraid nobody could help :/

Comment: No none ... and i also tried [link](https://github.com/ouhouhsami/django-progressbarupload) their demoApp it didn't worked either ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It clearly is a bug in webkit based browsers, here's the relevant thread:

[Ajax form upload progress bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16200409/ajax-form-upload-progress-bar)

Also here is the relevant github issue:

https://github.com/ouhouhsami/django-progressbarupload/issues/2

To comprehend, webkit doesn't allow to make ajax calls while uploading file, the usual workaround is to use dynamically created iframe (mentioned in above SO thread).

Answer (score 6):

It's not the best solution (and not so consistent) but it will be the easiest to implement.

Create js file e.g. progress_bar.js

In your admin.py

```
class YouSuperModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...
    class Media:
        js = ['/static/js/progress_bar.js']
    ...
```

In progress_bar.js

```
(function($){   
$(function(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#form_id" ).submit(function( event ) {
          event.preventDefault();

          var post_data = new FormData($("form")[0]);

          $.ajax({
              xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                var new_div = document.createElement('div');

                new_div.innerHTML = '<progress id="progressBar" value="0" max="100" style="width:300px;"></progress><h3 id="status"></h3><p id="loaded_n_total"></p>';
                document.getElementsByClassName('submit-row')[0].appendChild(new_div)

                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", progressHandler, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("load", completeHandler, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("error", errorHandler, false);
                xhr.addEventListener("abort", abortHandler, false);

                return xhr;
              },
                url: window.location.href,// to allow add and edit
                type: "POST",
                data: post_data,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    window.location.replace("/admin/yourapp/yoursupermodel/");
              }
            });
        });
    });
});  
})(django.jQuery);
```

The idea is to prevent default form submition, create new XMLHttpRequest, inject progressbar with messages and then send the data showing the process.

It is very important to set **processData: false, contentType: false,** otherwise it will not handle the file in the form

And finaly in your progress_bar.js set event handlers for the progress bar itself.

```
function _(el) {
  return document.getElementById(el);
}

function progressHandler(event) {
  _("loaded_n_total").innerHTML = "Uploaded " + event.loaded + " bytes of " + event.total;
  var percent = (event.loaded / event.total) * 100;
  _("progressBar").value = Math.round(percent);
  _("status").innerHTML = Math.round(percent) + "% uploaded... please wait";
}

function completeHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = event.target.responseText;
  _("progressBar").value = 0; //wil clear progress bar after successful upload
}

function errorHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Failed";

}

function abortHandler(event) {
  _("status").innerHTML = "Upload Aborted";
}
```

**NOTE:** In order not to have html page appearing  under the form after success you have to change your view that returns HttpResponse object or simply change the window.location.

The described method should work for any form with django.

Comment: I have used your solution in my Django project, and it worked straight away. However, as I am completely new to full stack dev world, I think I am a bit too green right now to understand how this actually works. My Django project at the moment uses if method == 'POST' conditional to start grabbing files attached in file input HTML elements. When I added your code with omitted event.preventDefault(); line, my website has started saving these files in 2 copies at the designated location. It confuses the hell out of me, since I did not specify in your function anywhere the location for the save.

Comment: If you don`t mind, could you please explain or send me to appropriate resources where I can learn what is actually happening the moment I declare var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest() and add a few event listeners for progress, success, fail etc? Does Ajax create a secondary stream for the file transfer, and does it parallel to the standard POST method by HTML form? Does the Back End code for working with these files I wrote in Django still get executed?

Comment: @Greem666 Sory for delay. Hope it will help for anyone.
XMLHttpRequest object helps to interact with servers.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest 
As I explained in the answer we are preventing default form submission with event.preventDefault(); and then the same django logic is used
If I remember correctly you will get html body in the response, so if you'd like to have redirect instead you can update you admin.py in order to have redirect in the desired view.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_urls

Comment: @urDMG. your example code works great for instantiating the progress bar in django on uploads to S3, however it seems to be too quick and will say 100% uploaded a good 5-10 seconds before the file is actually uploaded and the page redirected. Any ideas on why this may be?

Comment: @Hayden the file is first uploaded to a temporary location - during this phase the progress bar goes from 0 to 100%. Then the file is copied (not moved) from the temporary location to the final destination, during which time the progress bar continues to show 100%. To avoid this behavior I have created a custom FileUploadHandler which uploads directly to the destination file and use it instead. Just copy the existing TemporaryFileUploadHandler class as your own custom handler and modify the code to not create a temporary file.

Answer (score -1):

## Just pass your upload url `django_upload_url`

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>File Uploader</title>
      <link href="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v2.2.3/uppy.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
    <button data-toggle="modal" data-target="#UploaderModal"><strong>Upload Files</strong></button>
    <div class="modal" id="UploaderModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <!-- Modal Header -->
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h4 class="modal-title">Upload Files</h4>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          </div>
            <div id="drag-drop-area"></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  
      <script src="https://releases.transloadit.com/uppy/v2.2.3/uppy.min.js"></script>
      <script>
        var uppy = new Uppy.Core()
          .use(Uppy.Dashboard, {
            inline: true,
            proudlyDisplayPoweredByUppy:false,
            target: '#drag-drop-area',
            showProgressDetails: true,
            width: 1000,
          })
          .use(Uppy.XHRUpload, {
              endpoint: '{% url 'django_upload_url'  %}',
              headers: {'X-CSRFToken': " {{csrf_token}} "},
              formData: true,
              fieldName: "file",
              limit:1
          })
        uppy.on('complete', (result) => {
          console.log('Upload complete! We’ve uploaded these files:', result.successful)
          location.reload();
        })
      </script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

> Upload multiple files with progress bar django
> [image: upload multiple files with progress bar django]