# Django Modelform progressbar for file upload

Tags: django, file-upload, django-forms, progress-bar

I'm using django 1.8. I would like to have a progressbar in my django modelform. As users will upload files of ~100 mb size, I would like to give them feedback that the progress is ongoing.

I found some explanations on how set up a progressbar with a "usual" view, like e.g. http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/upload-to-django-with-progress-bar-using-ajax-and-jquery/ but I'm using a modelform, so I don't know how to modify these instructions to fit in a modelform.

I also tried out django-progressbarupload (https://github.com/ouhouhsami/django-progressbarupload). It doesn't show any progressbar; I have no clue why. Maybe it is because I'm using django 1.8

Additionally I tried this [Progress bar for FileField upload in a ModelForm (Django)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28014386/progress-bar-for-filefield-upload-in-a-modelform-django) which didn't work either. It keeps telling my browser does not support HTML5 and also doesn't show the file container nor the progressbar.

Is there any security issues that is preventing above solutions from working (tested on Firefox 38 and chrome 41)? How would I implement my own upload method in a modelform? How are other programmers dealing with this issue?

Any working examples or hints are very much appreciated.

Comment: Please check my answer, probably it will help someone https://stackoverflow.com/a/49024766/7396169

Answer (score 3):

Somehow solved the problem now on my own by using [`django-progressbarupload`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-progressbarupload/).

It seems like the development webserver of my django project is acting too fast for the progressbar to react, since the file transfer is only happening locally.
I realized that when I tried a bigger file (like >50 MB) and only in Chrome. It seems like Chrome and Firefox are behaving differently. I can't really tell what exactly the difference is, as the behavior of Firefox seems not to be consistent.

I played a bit more and added a sleep of some millisecondes to the file progressbarupload/uploadhandler.py like so:

```
from time import sleep

[...]

def receive_data_chunk(self, raw_data, start):
    if self.cache_key:
        data = cache.get(self.cache_key)
        data['uploaded'] += self.chunk_size
        cache.set(self.cache_key, data)
        print "receive_data chunk called"

        sleep(0.005)
    return raw_data

[...]
```

additionally you can also uncomment the line

```
console.log(data);
```

in `progressbarupload/static/js/progress_bar.js`

Hope this will help anybody dealing with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to keep the progress logic at the client side.

You can use this small project to popup an upload progress bar: https://github.com/jakobadam/bootstrap-uploadprogress

More info:
https://aarhusworks.com/2015/05/27/bootstrap-uploadprogress.html

Comment: Blog link is down