# Return percentage uploaded via php

Tags: php, jquery, upload, progress-bar

In my current setup I'm uploading an image via a form in form.php. This form is handled in a new php file called upload.php that is called via teh action and detects a when a post is made.

In the form.php I've got a Jquery progressbar ready to be animated

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({ value: 0 });
```

How do I get the '0' that comes after value, to be updated with the status of the upload?
Can I use php to generate a percentage of upload complete? I want to keep my upload form in HTML and I want to use jquery to animate the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use php to make callback, but you can make it with jQuery.

Look at this: [File upload progress bar with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery)

Comment: That code returns dozens of errors to me, mostly about functions not existing. Is this apply-able to my situations? I'm not using ajax to send the form, but using a newly opened php file to proces it.

Comment: Make sure you have installed latest version of jquery and jquery form plugin ( http://www.malsup.com/jquery/form/#download ). Also in accepted solution one "});" is missing.

Comment: I did find the missing });. I then however get the error that ajaxForm is not a valid function. Most likely because I am not using Ajax for my upload.

Comment: You just need to add jquery form plugin: malsup.com/jquery/form/#download and this error will be solved.

Comment: That did indeed fix the error. And the script is working now. It did however convert my form to an ajax call, and now my second page is loaded within the first. I've also noticed that the percentage does not calculate percentage uploaded, but goes to 100% once the script is finished.
Not an answer to my question, but very interesting none the less. Therefor +1'd.

I'm going to have a go at it with APC. Will keep you posted if that works out.