# [javascript]:How to achieve cross-site (cross-domain) directory upload in jquery.form plugin?

Tags: jquery, ajax, upload, directory

The thing i met with the ajaxForm plugin as following:

HTML:

```
<form id="uploadForm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" directory webkitdirectory name="fileToUpload" />
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("input[name='fileToUpload']").change(function() {
    var form = $('#uploadForm');
    form.attr('action', uploadURL);
    form.ajaxSubmit({
        uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
            var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
            console.log('percentVal', percentVal);
        },
        complete: function(xhr) {
            console.log('completed');
        },
        success: function() {
            console.log('success!!!!');
        }
        });
    return false;
});
```

The problem is i cannot even set the `uploadProgress`, once this callback was set, i got the `405 Method Not Allowed` error. But if i removed `uploadProgress` from the `ajaxSubmit`'s options, only `success` and `complete` callback were left, the upload operation executed correctly.

That confused me a lot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [File upload progress bar with jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery)

Comment: I edited my question, could you please take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i got the answer. It is about the cross-domain issue.

Once i deploy my apps in the same web-container, the issue was gone. But i still confused about this. Why the `uploadProgress` could not even set while sending cross-domain request?