# Upload multiple image using AJAX, PHP and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, image-uploading

I have a lot of problem to upload multiple images using AJAX. I write this code:

**HTML**

```
<form id="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="drop" class="drop-area">
        <div class="drop-area-label">
            Drop image here
        </div>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple/>
    </div>

    <ul class="gallery-image-list" id="uploads">
    <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
    </ul>
</form>
<div id="listTable"></div>
```

**jQuery/AJAX**

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name^='file']", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var This    =   this,
        display =   $("#uploads");

    // list all file data
    $.each(This.files, function(i, obj){
        // for each image run script asynchronous
        (function(i) {
            // get data from input file
            var file = This.files[i],
                name = file.name,
                size = file.size,
                type = file.type,
                lastModified        =   file.lastModified,
                lastModifiedDate    =   file.lastModifiedDate,
                webkitRelativePath  =   file.webkitRelativePath,
                slice               =   file.slice,
                i = i;

            // DEBUG
       /*
            var acc = []
            $.each(file, function(index, value) {
                acc.push(index + ": " + value);
            });
            alert(JSON.stringify(acc));
        */

            $.ajax({
                url:'/ajax/upload.php',
                contentType: "multipart/form-data",
                data:{
                        "image":
                        {
                            "name":name,
                            "size":size,
                            "type":type,
                            "lastModified":lastModified,
                            "lastModifiedDate":lastModifiedDate,
                            "webkitRelativePath":webkitRelativePath,
                            //"slice":slice,
                        }
                    },
                type: "POST",
                // Custom XMLHttpRequest
                xhr: function() {
                    var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    // Check if upload property exists
                    if(myXhr.upload)
                    {
                        // For handling the progress of the upload
                        myXhr.upload.addEventListener("progress",progressHandlingFunction, false); 
                    }
                    return myXhr;
                },
                cache: false,
                success : function(data){
                    // load ajax data
                    $("#listTable").append(data);
                }
            });
            // display progress
            function progressHandlingFunction(e){
                if(e.lengthComputable){
                    var perc = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total)*100);
                    perc = ( (perc >= 100) ? 100 : ( (perc <= 0) ? 0 : 0 ) );
                $("#progress"+i+" > div")
                    .attr({"aria-valuenow":perc})
                        .css("width", perc+"%");
                }
            }
            // display list of files
            display.append('<li>'+name+'</li><div class="progress" id="progress'+i+'">'
                    +'<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">'
                    +'</div></div>');
        })(i);
    }); 
});
```

I've tried a various versions and I never succeed to send multiple data through ajax. I have tried in this way what you see above, and now I get only POST informations. I understand why i get POST but I need to send FILES information and I do not know where I'm wrong.

I not work the first time with ajax and often use it for most projects but I have never used to send multiple files and that bothering me now.

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify: 1. contentType is `multipart/form-data` but data is not (jQuery.param will convert js object into `x-www-form-urlencoded` instead), so data will be lost in translation. What do you want to transfer and how?  2. Actual image data is not uploaded, is this intentional?  3. One ajax is called for *each* file, causing lots of connection and conflict in progress handler, is this intentional? 4. I do not see any drag drop code. Do you want it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try utilizing `json` to upload , process `file` object

html

```
<div id="drop" class="drop-area ui-widget-header">
  <div class="drop-area-label">Drop image here</div>
</div>
<br />
<form id="upload">
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" multiple="true" accepts="image/*" />
  <ul class="gallery-image-list" id="uploads">
    <!-- The file uploads will be shown here -->
  </ul>
</form>
<div id="listTable"></div>
```

css

```
  #uploads {
      display:block;
      position:relative;
  } 

  #uploads li {
      list-style:none;
  }

  #drop {
      width: 90%;
      height: 100px;
      padding: 0.5em;
      float: left;
      margin: 10px;
      border: 8px dotted grey;
  }

  #drop.hover {
      border: 8px dotted green;
  }

  #drop.err {
      border: 8px dotted orangered;
  }
```

js

```
var display = $("#uploads"); // cache `#uploads`, `this` at `$.ajax()`
var droppable = $("#drop")[0]; // cache `#drop` selector
$.ajaxSetup({
    context: display,
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: function (jqxhr, settings) {
        // pre-process `file`
        var file = JSON.parse(
                   decodeURIComponent(settings.data.split(/=/)[1])
                   );
        // add `progress` element for each `file`
        var progress = $("<progress />", {
                "class": "file-" + (!!$("progress").length 
                         ? $("progress").length 
                         : "0"),
                "min": 0,
                "max": 0,
                "value": 0,
                "data-name": file.name
        });
        this.append(progress, file.name + "<br />");
        jqxhr.name = progress.attr("class"); 
    }
});

var processFiles = function processFiles(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // process `input[type=file]`, `droppable` `file`
    var files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
    var images = $.map(files, function (file, i) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var dfd = new $.Deferred();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            dfd.resolveWith(file, [e.target.result])
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([file], {
            "type": file.type
        }));
        return dfd.then(function (data) {
            return $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/echo/json/",
                data: {
                    "file": JSON.stringify({
                            "file": data,
                            "name": this.name,
                            "size": this.size,
                            "type": this.type
                    })
                },
                xhr: function () {
                    // do `progress` event stuff
                    var uploads = this.context;
                    var progress = this.context.find("progress:last");
                    var xhrUpload = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    if (xhrUpload.upload) {
                        xhrUpload.upload.onprogress = function (evt) {
                            progress.attr({
                                    "max": evt.total,
                                    "value": evt.loaded
                            })
                        };
                        xhrUpload.upload.onloadend = function (evt) {
                            var progressData = progress.eq(-1);
                            console.log(progressData.data("name")
                                    + " upload complete...");
                            var img = new Image;
                            $(img).addClass(progressData.eq(-1)
                            .attr("class"));
                            img.onload = function () {
                                if (this.complete) {
                                  console.log(
                                      progressData.data("name")
                                      + " preview loading..."
                                  );
                                };

                            };
                        uploads.append("<br /><li>", img, "</li><br />");
                        };
                    }
                    return xhrUpload;
                }
            })
            .then(function (data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
                console.log(data)
                this.find("img[class=" + jqxhr.name + "]")
                .attr("src", data.file)
                .before("<span>" + data.name + "</span><br />");
                return data
            }, function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(errorThrown);
                return errorThrown
            });
        })
    });
    $.when.apply(display, images).then(function () {
        var result = $.makeArray(arguments);
        console.log(result.length, "uploads complete");
    }, function err(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown)
    })
};

$(document)
.on("change", "input[name^=file]", processFiles);
// process `droppable` events
droppable.ondragover = function () {
    $(this).addClass("hover");
    return false;
};

droppable.ondragend = function () {
    $(this).removeClass("hover")
    return false;
};

droppable.ondrop = function (e) {
    $(this).removeClass("hover");
    var image = Array.prototype.slice.call(e.dataTransfer.files)
        .every(function (img, i) {
        return /^image/.test(img.type)
    });
    e.preventDefault();
    // if `file`, file type `image` , process `file`
    if (!!e.dataTransfer.files.length && image) {
            $(this).find(".drop-area-label")
            .css("color", "blue")
            .html(function (i, html) {
            $(this).delay(3000, "msg").queue("msg", function () {
                $(this).css("color", "initial").html(html)
            }).dequeue("msg");
            return "File dropped, processing file upload...";
        });
        processFiles(e);
    } else {
            // if dropped `file` _not_ `image`
            $(this)
            .removeClass("hover")
            .addClass("err")
            .find(".drop-area-label")
            .css("color", "darkred")
            .html(function (i, html) {
            $(this).delay(3000, "msg").queue("msg", function () {
                $(this).css("color", "initial").html(html)
                .parent("#drop").removeClass("err")
            }).dequeue("msg");
            return "Please drop image file...";
        });
    };
};
```

php

```
<?php
  if (isset($_POST["file"])) {
    // do php stuff
    // call `json_encode` on `file` object
    $file = json_encode($_POST["file"]);
    // return `file` as `json` string
    echo $file;
  };
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/0hm09yqo/

Comment: Question, in PHP, string `$file` I use for handling with data and can do upload like with `$_FILE[]` ?

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić You are welcome:) `$file` at `php` portion at post _not_ same as `$_FILES` . `$_FILES` appear to require `<form>` element , with `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute. Approach at post utilizes `JSON` data type to post , process response. See http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php , http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2 , http://www.sitepoint.com/handle-file-uploads-php/ ,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3586919/why-would-files-be-empty-when-uploading-files-to-php .

Comment: I'm asking because I want to resize the image, rename, make thumb and save in folders. I'll look this links and try. Thanks again.

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić The actual image should be a `data-uri` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs at `file.file` , image name at `file.name` .