# HTML send input as file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am building a simple HTML image uploader. The user can select many images using a file input, and for each image a preview is created.

To send the images to the server I was thinking about attaching an `input` to each image so that they are automatically sent when the form is submitted.
An element would look like this:

```
<div>
  <input type="file" class="hidden" name="model[images][]">
  <img src="base 64 image">
</div>
```

The problem is that of course I can't set an arbitrary file for the file input, so what's the simplest solution to send many files from the same form without using a single input?

Comment: Since you'll be using a dataURL in order to preview the images, you can just copy each of them into a separate hidden input, uploading each file as the text contained in it. You could then turn them back into files at the other end. I guess you may also wish to send info like the original filesize and name too. I'd construct a JSON string that contained the base64 dataURL of each image along with its original name and size. I'd then upload that JSON string.

Comment: Yes I also thought about this, just wanted to keep it simple on the server side. As I'm using rails it would be nice to upload the input as a file so it is automatically saved as a temporary file on the serever. Of course if it's not possible that will be the only alternative

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/28856729/

Answer (score 1):

In [modern browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData#Browser_compatibility), you can use the [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) object and its [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) method :

```
var input  = document.querySelector('input');
var formdata = new FormData();

var nb = 0;
input.onchange= function(e){
    // since we can't write in a fileList, we have to add an index so our server can access each files
    formdata.append('file_'+nb++, this.files[0], this.files[0].name);
    // we also need to keep track of this index
    formdata.append('file_count', nb);
    }
function sendToServer(){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', 'script.php');
    xhr.send(formdata);
}
```

Then in **script.php**

```
$file_count = $_POST['file_count'];
for($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++){
    // Do whatever with your files
    echo $_FILES['file_'.$i]['name'];
    }
```