# Setting a input type file with query, inserting image saved as base64

Tags: jquery, client

I have a Base64 image string, i need to set the value of an input type file field, i have no control of the server side, or of the site, so it has to be done like this.

Is this possible?

**FB API request / response on img upload**

[image]

The response is a very long jS string setting some values, its very very very long, cannot post due to char restriction on SO.

This seems to be how the image is addeded to a post:

```
<input type="file" class="_n _5f0v" title="Vælg en fil at overføre" multiple="1" name="composer_unpublished_photo[]" aria-label="Føj billeder til dit opslag" id="js_h">
```

This is what happens when a post is posted, containing an image, the post only seems to reference the image, that has been pre-uploaded, on the prev request i posted.

[image]

Comment: _"need to set the value of an input type file field"_ Can include `html` , `js` at Question ? What is expected result ?

Comment: I can include JS ofc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> need to set the value of an input type file field, i have no control
>   of the server side, or of the site, so it has to be done like this.
>
> Is this possible?

No, it is not possible to "set" the [`FileList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileList) object , or `File` object of an `input` element

> An object of this type is returned by the files property of the HTML
>   `<input>` element; this lets you access the list of files selected with
>   the `<input type="file">` element.
>
> var file = document.getElementById('fileItem').files[0];
>
> Method overview
>
> `File item(index);`
>
> Properties
>
> Attribute Type    Description
>
> length    integer A read-only value indicating the number of files in the list.

Comment: So i have to mimic the API call, rather then just call the .submit() on the form

Comment: @IvanRistic _"I can include JS ofc"_ Yes , would perhaps be helpful for viewers of Question to reproduce `html` , `js` ? _"So i have to mimic the API call, rather then just call the .submit() on the form"_ Not certain interpret Question correctly ? What is expected result ?

Comment: I need to auto upload an image to a facebook post. Using a chrome ext.

Comment: Setting the text is easy, but uploading the image is quite hard since i cannot set the value of the input field and just mimic a .click(), i guess i have to send a request to FB, to get it uploaded with the post.

Comment: Try utilizing `$.post(url, {file:file})` . Not certain what format api expects file as ? Will api accept `Blob` ? , or `json` object ? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

Comment: It seems like facebook uploads the image as a form multitype, and returns some javascript. This seems quite complicated with param names that do not make sense, wish i could hire someone for this. Any suggestions on where to find facebook unofficial API experts :- P

Images have been added to the edit from charles proxy.