# How to get the local image path when browse the image in jquery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Is it possible to get the image path from where it is selected in jquery before upload to a particular folder.

Comment: _"Is it possible to get the image path from where it is selected in jquery before upload to a particular folder."_ No. It is possible to retrieve image `name`

Comment: Any other way to display an image before upload to a folder,which means display the image on browsing

Comment: Yes, image could be displayed when selected by user, before upload. Can include `html` , `js` at Question ?

Comment: Help me to display the image

Comment: **[This link](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Show-Display-image-preview-before-upload-using-jQuery.aspx)** might help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try utilizing `change` event , `URL.createObjectURL` with `this.files[0]` as argument

```js
$("input[type=file]").on("change", function() {
  $("[for=file]").html(this.files[0].name);
  $("#preview").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]));
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input id="file" type="file" accepts="image/*" /><br />
<label for="file"></label><br />
<img id="preview" />
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your support.Here I need to display multiple images also.I have the below code for displaying images in  dynamically generated div.div = $('<div class="photoclass" />');
            img = $('<img />', { 'src': URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]) }).prependTo(div);
            div.appendTo('.photo_inner');   Any idea please help?

Comment: @Neethu _"need to display multiple images also."_  Not appear at original Question ? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Tried using a loop for each `this.files` ? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/