# Convert img Javascript variable to $_FILES['name']['tmp_name'];

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I can convert javascript functions to php to use it on server side through:

in JS:

```
$("#containerphp").load("save.php", {firstValueContainer:firstValue, secValueContainer:secValue});
```

in php (save.php):

```
$firstVal = $_REQUEST['firstValueContainer'];
$secVal = $_REQUEST['secValueContainer'];
```

It works fine but now I need to send a image variable (var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");) from javascript to php. I saw that the following code works to send it but in a form (without JS):

```
$_FILES['name']['tmp_name'];
```

Anybody knows how can I convert my image from JS to php in this context?

Thank you all.

Comment: Try sending `data URI` returned from `var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");` to server side , see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

Comment: Thanks, I´ll check it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
var image = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

and send it to php

> $_FILE can not be used here because $_FILE is An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method.

convert javascript functions to php to use it on server side through:

```
$("#containerphp").load("save.php", {firstValueContainer:firstValue, secValueContainer:secValue, imageValue: image});
```