# How to post an image in base64 encoding via .ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have some javascript code that uploads an image to a server. Below is the ajax call that works correctly.

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1/analyses?',
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: '{ "Url": "http://images.takungpao.com/2012/1115/20121115073901672.jpg" }',
})
```

I now need to upload the image a a base64 encoding e.g.

```
data: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA..........gAooooAKKKKACiiigD//Z'
```

But that doesn't work, i.e. the server doesn't recognise the data I send and complains.

Does anyone know what the correct format is for sending base64 encoded data in the AJAX call ?

Comment: Doesn't work how? Errors? No errors?

Comment: _"But that doesn't work."_ Where is image posted as `data URI` at `js` at Question ? What is purpose of `$.param(params)` ? What is `params` ? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

Comment: Can someone please answer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462008/getting-status-code400-bad-request-when-calling-microsoft-azure-emotion-api-w?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Thanks for all the answers which helped me along.

I had also posted the question to the forums on 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/807ee18d-45e5-410b-a339-c8dcb3bfa25b/testing-project-oxford-ocr-how-to-use-a-local-file-in-base64-for-example?forum=mlapi (more Project Oxford specific) and between their answers and your's I've got a solution.

1. You need to send a Blob
2. You need to set the `processData:false` and `contentType: 'application/octet-stream'` options in the .ajax call

So my solution looks like this

First a function to make the blob (This is copied verbatim from someone more gifted than I)

```
makeblob = function (dataURL) {
            var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
            if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
                var parts = dataURL.split(',');
                var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
                var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
                return new Blob([raw], { type: contentType });
            }
            var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
            var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
            var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
            var rawLength = raw.length;

            var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

            for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
                uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });
        }
```

and then

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1/ocr?' + $.param(params),
    type: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    data: makeblob('data:image/jpeg;base64,9j/4AAQSkZJRgA..........gAooooAKKKKACiiigD//Z'
 })
.done(function(data) {alert("success");})
.fail(function() {alert("error");});
```

Comment: Vote for this: https://github.com/felixrieseberg/project-oxford/issues/15#issuecomment-243188637

Comment: This works well, `makeBlob` turns the data into a format that can be passed to the emotion API. Great! This should be marked as an answer?

Comment: i was struggling with sending the local file data to face detect api for last two days, this worked like a charm. Thanks

Comment: Also, changing the contentType: 'image/png' worked well for me. Only advantage was that the target server recognized it as image & I still had to add .PNG extension to open the file

Answer (score 3):

This is some working code from my own application.  You will need to change the `contentType` and `data` args in your ajax operations.

```
    var video = that.vars.video;
    var code = document.createElement("canvas");

    code.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, code.width, code.height);

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = code.toDataURL();    

    $.ajax({
        url: '/scan/submit',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { data: code.toDataURL(), userid: userid },
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.error) {
                alert(data.error);
                return;
            }
            // do something here.
        }, 
        error : function (r, s, e) {
                alert("Unexpected error:" + e);
                console.log(r);
                console.log(s);
                console.log(e);
            } 
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//After received the foto, convert to byte - C# code
Dim imagem = imagemBase64.Split(",")(1)
Dim bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imagem)
```

You load the image in canvas, not necessary upload to server.

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.drawImage(img, selection.x, selection.y, selection.w, selection.h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

var ctxPreview = avatarCanvas.getContext('2d');
ctxPreview.clearRect(0, 0, ctxPreview.width, ctxPreview.height);


ctxPreview.drawImage(img, selection.x, selection.y, selection.w, selection.h, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

$('#avatarCanvas').attr('src', canvas.toDataURL());
$('#hdImagembase64').val(canvas.toDataURL());
```

See, this code get image and draw in canvas, after draw you get base64 string with canvas.toDataURL()

try this :D

Answer (score -2):

The data parameter for jQuery's $.ajax call can be a String, Object, or Array. Based on the working example you gave, it looks like your upload script expects a parameter called "Url":

```
data: '{ "Url": "http://images.takungpao.com/2012/1115/20121115073901672.jpg" }'
```

If you wanted to pass the parameter as an Object, you might try:

```
data: {
  Url: 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA..........gAooooAKKKKACiiigD//Z'
}
```

If you want to pass it as a String, you might try:

```
data: '{ "Url": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgA..........gAooooAKKKKACiiigD//Z"}'
```