# Microsoft Cognitive Services: Uploading image

Tags: image, mobile, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to upload an image to the Microsoft Computer Vision API from a mobile device, but I am constantly receiving a 400 Bad Request for Invalid File Format "Input data is not a valid image". The documentation states that I can send the data as application/octet-stream in the following form:

> [Binary image data]

I have the data of the image in terms of base64 encoding ("/9j/4AAQSkZJ.........."), and I also have the image as a FILE_URI, but I can't seem to figure out the format in which to send the data. Here is a sample code:

```
$(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.projectoxford.ai/vision/v1.0/describe",
        beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
            // Request headers
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
            xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", computerVisionKey);
        },
        type: "POST",
        // Request body
        data: base64image,
        processData: false        
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      alert("success");
    })
    .fail(function(error) {
      alert("fail");
    });
});
```

I've tried the following:

- [base64image]
- {base64image}
- "data:image/jpeg;base64," + base64image
- "image/jpeg;base64," + base64image

and more.

I did tested these on the Computer Vision API console. Is it because base64 encoded binary isn't an acceptable format? Or am I sending it in the incorrect format completely?

Note: The operation works when sending a URL as application/json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [Emotion API Project Oxford base64 image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361350/emotion-api-project-oxford-base64-image), or go directly to the code snippet here: [How to post an image in base64 encoding via .ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047648/how-to-post-an-image-in-base64-encoding-via-ajax/34064793#34064793) .

Since this is a recurring topic, I've made a feature request to make the APIs handle data URIs directly, on [UserVoice](https://cognitive.uservoice.com/forums/356325-apis/suggestions/14858679-support-data-uris-in-image-apis-vision-emotion-fa).

Comment: Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to add this in case it helps anyone else. The answer referenced by cthrash above works fine, but it lead me to a simpler way that doesn't convert the image to base64 and then back to binary.

Just read the image as an ArrayBuffer and use that to construct a new Blob for the body of the post. Also, don't forget to set processData to false. The full solution looks like this:

```
//onChange event handler for file input
function fileInputOnChange(evt) {
    var imageFile = evt.target.files[0];     
    var reader = new FileReader();
    var fileType;

    //wire up the listener for the async 'loadend' event
    reader.addEventListener('loadend', function () {

        //get the result of the async readAsArrayBuffer call
        var fileContentArrayBuffer = reader.result;

            //now that we've read the file, make the ajax call
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect",
                beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
                    // Request headers
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
                    xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "<your subscription key goes here>");
                },
                type: "POST",

                //don't forget this!
                processData: false,

                //NOTE: the fileContentArrayBuffer is the single element 
                //IN AN ARRAY passed to the constructor!
                data: new Blob([fileContentArrayBuffer], { type: fileType })
            })
            .done(function (data) {
                console.log(data)
            })
            .fail(function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            });

    });
    if (imageFile) {
        //save the mime type of the file
        fileType = imageFile.type;

        //read the file asynchronously
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(imageFile);
    }    
}
```