# microsoft cognitive - face detect - upload image from local

Tags: json, api, face-detection, azure-cognitive-services

I'm new with Face Recognition.
I've seen a lot of question but I think I didn't found an answer yet.

I've understood that to upload an image from Web I have to use Content-Type application/json and then I have to put the image url in JSON field, like below.

```
{
"url":"http://example.com/1.jpg"
}
```

But, if I would upload an image from local, i should use Content-Type application/octet-stream.
Now, my question is: what do I have to insert in JSON field in this case?

Sorry for my poor english and thanks in advance for your answers.

p.s. here you can find the tutorial I was following:
https://westcentralus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236/console

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This has been answered [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37900554/microsoft-cognitive-services-uploading-image).

Basically the body should be the raw bits of the image.

Comment: yes, thanks, i've tried to understand the code but i haven't understood what I have to do, sincerelly.