# Posting An Image from Webcam to Azure Face Api

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to upload an image that I get from my webcam to the Microsoft Azure Face Api. I get the image from canvas.toDataUrl(‘image/png’) which contains the Data Uri. I change the Content Type to application/octet-stream and when I attach the Data Uri to the post request, I get a Bad Request (400) Invalid Face Image. If I change the attached data to a Blob, I stop receiving errors however I only get back an empty array instead of a JSON object. I would really appreciate any help for pointing me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: The result of `toDataUrl` is already a valid URL. Try using `application/json` and sending it the `url` property with that result

Comment: When I just attach what I get from toDataUrl and change the Content-Type to application, I get a JSON Parsing Error.

Comment: You need to send json. `{ "url": <your-data-url-here> }`

Comment: I am still getting a JSON parse error.

Comment: My JSON object looks like {"url": realData}

Comment: I've tried attaching both the original data object i get from canvas.toDataURL as well as one where I replace the original /^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/ with a blank.

Comment: I switched it to a blob format and it worked. Input the data you get from canvas.toDataUrl() into    fetch(data) .then(res => res.blob()).then(blobData => { and then send the blobData to the api }

Comment: can you please post the code that made it work? Thanks.

Comment: added the solution down below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got the answer finally by sending the image as a blob object. You first grab the image from canvas with:

```
let data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
```

Afterwards, you can reformat it to a blob data object by running:

```
fetch(data)
  .then(res => res.blob())
  .then(blobData => {
    // attach blobData as the data for the post request
  }
```

You will also need to switch the Content-Type of the post request to "application/octet-stream"

Answer (score 4):

Oh you're in such luck, i've just (successfully!) attempted this 2 days ago.

Sending base64-encoded JPEGs to Face API is seriously inefficient, The ratio of encoded output bytes to input bytes is 4:3 (33% overhead). Just send a byte array, it works, the docs [mention it briefly](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236).

[image: send-jpeg-as-octet-stream]

And try to read as JPEG not PNG, that's just wasting bandwidth for webcam footage.

```js
    ...

    var dataUri = canvas.toDataURL('image/' + format);
    var data = dataUri.split(',')[1];
    var mimeType = dataUri.split(';')[0].slice(5)

    var bytes = window.atob(data);
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(bytes.length);
    var byteArr = new Uint8Array(buf);

    for (var i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        byteArr[i] = bytes.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return byteArr;
```

Now use `byteArr` as your payload (`data:`) in `$.ajax()` for jQuery or `iDontUnderStandHowWeGotHereAsAPeople()` in any other hipster JS framework people use these days.

The reverse-hipster way of doing it is:

```js
var payload = byteArr;

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'https://SERVICE_URL');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
xhr.send(payload);
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment about JPEG! I tried your solution however I am getting a 400: Invalid face image error when I am posting to Microsofts api. Did you run into this problem as well?

Comment: No. Use something like https://requestb.in or Fiddler to see the raw request you are making. The body should look "binary"-ish to the naked eye with the `JFIF` string somewhere on the first two lines (if you are indeed sending a JPEG now).

Comment: The answer for me was the makeblob function described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047648/how-to-post-an-image-in-base64-encoding-via-ajax/34064793#34064793 I could not get this method to work

Comment: Thanks Mate. You just saved my day!

Answer (score 3):

To extend Dalvor's answer: this is the AJAX call that works for me:

```
fetch(data)
.then(res => res.blob())
.then(blobData => {
  $.post({
      url: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect",
      contentType: "application/octet-stream",
      headers: {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '<YOUR-KEY-HERE>'
      },
      processData: false,
      data: blobData
    })
    .done(function(data) {
      $("#results").text(JSON.stringify(data));

    })
    .fail(function(err) {
      $("#results").text(JSON.stringify(err));
    })
```

Full demo code here: https://jsfiddle.net/miparnisari/b1zzpvye/

Answer (score 1):

For saving someone's 6 hours, I appended my right code.
I hope this code helps you.

## Tools

- React
- Typescript
- [React-webcam](https://github.com/mozmorris/react-webcam)
- Mac OS
- [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios)

## Code

#### index.tsx

Constants and ref

```
/**
 * Constants
 */
const videoConstraints = {
  width: 1280,
  height: 720,
  facingMode: 'user',
};
/**
 * Refs
 */
const webcamRef = React.useRef<Webcam>(null);
```

Call back function

```
const capture = React.useCallback(() => {
  const base64Str = webcamRef.current!.getScreenshot() || '';
  const s = base64Str.split(',');
  const blob = b64toBlob(s[1]);
  callCognitiveApi(blob);
}, [webcamRef]);
```

In render

```
<Webcam audio={false} ref={webcamRef} screenshotFormat="image/jpeg" videoConstraints={videoConstraints} />
<button onClick={capture}>Capture photo</button>
```

#### base64toBlob

Thanks to [creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

```
export const b64toBlob = (b64DataStr: string, contentType = '', sliceSize = 512) => {
  const byteCharacters = atob(b64DataStr);
  const byteArrays = [];

  for (let offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
    const slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

    const byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
    for (let i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
      byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    const byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);
    byteArrays.push(byteArray);
  }

  const blob = new Blob(byteArrays, { type: contentType });
  return blob;
};
```

#### callCognitiveApi

```
import axios from 'axios';

const subscriptionKey: string = 'This_is_your_subscription_key';
const url: string = 'https://this-is-your-site.cognitiveservices.azure.com/face/v1.0/detect';
export const callCognitiveApi = (data: any) => {
  const config = {
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/octet-stream', 'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': subscriptionKey },
  };
  const response = axios
    .post(url, data, config)
    .then((res) => {
      console.log(res);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
};
```

## Result

[image: Result screenshot]