# Cognitive Services Response Bad Request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, azure-cognitive-services

I am not understanding What went wrong in the following code, I am using MS-Cognitive Services for Face API and for that converting image into blob (Code Below)

```
var ab = [];
var img = new Image();
img.src = imageUri; // imageUri for FilePath
img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = $(window).width();
canvas.height = $(window).height();
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
alert(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, ""));

var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
var rawLength = raw.length;
var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);
    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
        uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }   var bb = new Blob([new Uint8Array(ab)]);
```

And Following Code to make an Ajax Call for Face Detection (MS-Cognitive Services)

```
var params = {
    "returnFaceId": "true",
    "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
    "returnFaceAttributes": "{string}",
};

$.ajax({
    url: "https://australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect?" + $.param(params),
    beforeSend: function (xhrObj) {
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
        xhrObj.setRequestHeader("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "KEY_GOES_HERE");
    },
    type: "POST",
    data: bb,
    processData: false,
})
    .done(function (data) {
        alert("Response Done::" +data);
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(" Status:: " + jqXHR.status + "  ResponseText is:: " + jqXHR.statusText + "");
    });
```

I am getting Response as 400-Bad Request. I do not understand where I am making mistake.? BTW, the whole thing is in same function. 
Can anyone please help me with it? Thank You.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/47004512/1623249

Comment: I guess I have some problem with Blob generation.

Comment: Yeah. I never managed to get it to work without using "fetch"

Comment: Do you have any other option than "fetch"??

Answer (score 0):

It Solved Problem with this

```
var params = {
    // Request parameters
    "returnFaceId": "true",
    "returnFaceLandmarks": "false",
    "returnFaceAttributes": "age,gender,headPose,smile,facialHair,glasses,emotion,hair,makeup,occlusion,accessories,blur,exposure,noise",
};
```