# How to send application/octet-steam image data to Microsoft Face API in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, azure-cognitive-services

I want to send Octet-Stream binary data to Microsoft Face API in Nodejs. I have a base64 encoded image data. I want to send it to the Face API. I'm using the following code:

```
var dataURItoBuffer = function (dataURL, callback) {
    var buff = new Buffer(dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|gif|jpeg);base64,/, ''), 'base64');
    callback(buff);
};

var sendImageToMicrosoftDetectEndPoint = function (imageData, callback) {
    console.log('Entered helper');
    dataURItoBuffer(imageData, function (buff) {
        request.post({
            url: keyConfig.microsoftDetectURL,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
                'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': keyConfig.microsoftApiKey
            },
            data: buff
        }, function (err, httpResponse, body) {
            console.log(body);
        });
    })
}
```

But it gives me this response:

```
{
  "error": {
     "code":"InvalidImageSize",
     "message":"Image size is too small."
   }
}
```

Comment: If you are struggling with it, please look https://stackoverflow.com/a/58854505/2627126.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
request.post({
    data: buff
}
```

Do

```
request.post({
    body: buff
}
```