# Getting `Status Code:400 Bad Request` When calling Microsoft Azure Emotion API with data of type `Content-Type:application/octet-stream`

Tags: javascript, angular, azure-cognitive-services, emotion

I'm trying to send data to [Microsoft Cognitive Services' Emotion API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/563b31ea778daf121cc3a5fa), in the form of `Content-Type: application/octet-stream`.

I'm getting the Base64 string of an image from a canvas by calling `canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 0.1);`(I've tried calling it with 1, 0.5, 0.2 as well, just to check whether it works and stops giving me errors)

Then with that Base64 string, I'm calling the EmotionService's `getUserEmotion` method.

I followed the instructions mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34047648/how-to-post-an-image-in-base64-encoding-via-ajax/34064793#34064793), to make an AJAX call using Angular's HttpClient. Here's what my service looks like:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable()
export class EmotionService {

  apiUrl: string = 'https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/emotion/v1.0/recognize';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getUserEmotion(userImageBlob) {
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers = headers.set('Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key', 'my-api-key-here');
    headers = headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, { "data": this.makeBlob(userImageBlob) }, { headers: headers });
  }

  makeBlob(dataURL) {
    var BASE64_MARKER = ';base64,';
    if (dataURL.indexOf(BASE64_MARKER) == -1) {
      var parts = dataURL.split(',');
      var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
      var raw = decodeURIComponent(parts[1]);
      return new Blob([raw], { type: contentType });
    }
    var parts = dataURL.split(BASE64_MARKER);
    var contentType = parts[0].split(':')[1];
    var raw = window.atob(parts[1]);
    var rawLength = raw.length;

    var uInt8Array = new Uint8Array(rawLength);

    for (var i = 0; i < rawLength; ++i) {
      uInt8Array[i] = raw.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([uInt8Array], { type: contentType });
  }

}
```

Here's what my Network Tab Looks Like for the request:

[image]

Follwing are the questions that I have:

1. In the SO Answer that I'm following, they've also specified that I should set the `processData:false` option for my AJAX call. But I'm not sure how to do that using Angular's `HttpClient`.
2. The `data` field in the request payload is also coming as empty. But when I debugged, I was getting proper Blob Object from the `makeBlob` method. Why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was doing a very silly thing here. The [API Documentation of the Emotion API](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5639d931ca73072154c1ce89/operations/563b31ea778daf121cc3a5fa) here says that it needs data as binary image data.

[image: API DOC of Emotion API]

But I was still giving it as JSON. I simply changed the implementation of `getUserEmotion` method. Instead of

```
return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, { "data": this.makeBlob(userImageBlob) }, { headers: headers });
```

I used this

```
return this.http.post(this.apiUrl, this.makeBlob(userImageBlob), { headers: headers });
```

**Hope this helps someone who's facing the same issue!**