# convert image to binary data . How can i do?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, binary

I have an problem with  sending binary data from ionic app.
The app capture an photo from camera in base64 format and she must send this in binary data format to API server. 
I have to sent the image at the azure cognitive service for image recognize.

this is my capture function :

public takeFoto(){

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 100,
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
  correctOrientation:true,
  saveToPhotoAlbum: true
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {

 this.myPhoto = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
 this.imgData = imageData;

}, (err) => {
 // Handle error

});



}
```

and this is my post function :

```
    classifica(){


this.crudService.postAzureApi( /*binary data*/ '','https://northeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v2.0/tag').then((result)=>{

        console.log(result);
        this.resultPost = result;

},(err)=> {

                        console.log(err);
                     this.resultPost = err;

});

}
```

the header are : content-type : application/octet-stream and apikey

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21227078/convert-base64-to-image-in-javascript-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Blob from a base64 string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16245767/creating-a-blob-from-a-base64-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert to an array of Bytes. There are tools to do so. For example [bin2c](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bin2c/).

Comment: Thanks but i have solved the problem through this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47462008/getting-status-code400-bad-request-when-calling-microsoft-azure-emotion-api-w