# access the data passed through FormData on clicking submit button

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, validation

I have a form with several input fields including file inputs.I am using jquery validate plugin.I need to submit the form using ajax.

HTML:

```
<form method="post" name="addstudent" id="registrationform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
some fields
<input type="submit" id="buttontext" 
    class="student_registrationform_button" value="submit" />
```

Jquery:

```
$('#buttontext').click(function(){
    $("#registrationform").validate({
           invalidHandler: function(event, validator) {    
          //some code        
    },
 submitHandler: function(form){
            formdata = false;
            if (window.FormData) {
                    formdata = new FormData();
                }
           var i = 0, len = $(".file").length, img, reader, file;
           $('.file').each(function() { var file = this.files[0];
            if (window.FileReader) {
                            reader = new FileReader();
                            reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                     }
                if (formdata) {
                    formdata.append("file", file);
                }
           });
          $.ajax({
                    url:  "process.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    //data: $(this).serialize(),
                    data: formdata,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false, 
                    success:function(data){  //alert(data);
                    console.log(data);return false;
          }
```

Process.php

When I check `echo 'action:'.var_dump($_POST);` ,its showing null string

Comment: //data: $(this).serialize(); why you commented serialization?

Comment: Try removing `FileReader()` portions, which convert `File` object to `data URI`; substituting `$_FILE` for `$_POST`

Comment: Since I need files name in the process page for uploading,I cannot use serialize.I need to use formdata() right.@VigneswaranS

Comment: @guest271314 My upload php scripts are in second page.How we can get the filenames for uplaoding in the next page(upload.php)

Comment: Try retrieve file name use `this.files[0].name`

Comment: @guest271314 I have multiple file input fields.How we can  pass the filename into second page like this.

Comment: @Techy See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    (function($) {
    $.fn.serializefiles = function() {
        var obj = $(this);

        var form_data = new FormData(this[0]);
        $.each($(obj).find('input[type="file[]"]'), function(i, tag) {
            $.each($(tag)[0].files, function(i, file) {
                form_data.append(tag.name, file);
            });
        });

        var params = $(obj).serializeArray();
        $.each(params, function (i, val) {
            form_data.append(val.name, val.value);
        });

        return form_data;
    };
    })(jQuery);


    var form_id = $('#registrationform');


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "process.php",
        data: form_id.serializefiles(),
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(data);return false;
        }


    });
```

Comment: This code will handle all your form data including files too. Kindly, check it. Thanks.

Comment: I have other input fields in form.Will I get those also

Comment: It will handle all the fields in your form with ID = "registrationform". Kindly, give it a try. I have also included "console.log(data);return false;", kindly, check your console for the response. Feel free to discuss any issue. Thanks.

Comment: You can add the code in submitHandler from "var form_id = $('#registrationform');" onwards. The rest of the code should be outside OR above "$('#buttontext').click(function(){" OR at the start of your .JS file. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't get the file names in the process.php when I use var_dump($_POST)

Comment: use var_dump(S_FILES)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97928/discussion-between-techy-and-user1544541).

Comment: I understood why the files are duplicating..its because you are appending filenames initially,then appending all form elements in to formdata

Comment: I am unaware how to check filenames are in formdata object in the function

Comment: you can access the data through form_data variable.
kindly print form_data in console and you'll get all the values.
Thanks.

Comment: How to check whether the formdata has filename@user1544541

Comment: why are you using formdata ?? Don't use it.

Comment: How can I check the filename is already appended in formdata.Suppose I ahve uploaded 2 same names.I need to append only one file to foemdata

Comment: So, you don't want to allow same name files, right?

Comment: form_data.append(tag.name, file);
console.log(file.name);

Comment: But how to compare file.name exist in formdata

Comment: please give me some time, and I'll assist you definitely. Thanks.

Comment: ok...I also checked for duplication of files.This also not working.. if(val.name!='file')
           {
                form_data.append(val.name, val.value);
            }

Comment: I edited the code regarding duplication. Kindly, check it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks bro..its now working...ANd doing  form_data.append(val.name, val.value); will not append the file inputs to formdata ,right???

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple function:

```
 submitHandler: function(form){
          formdata = new FormData(form);
          $.ajax({
                    url:  "process.php",
                    type: 'POST',
                    //data: $(this).serialize(),
                    data: formdata,
                    cache: false,
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false, 
                    success:function(data){  //alert(data);
                    console.log(data);return false;
          }
```