# Upload file in WPF application using a web api which expects IFormFile parameter

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, asp.net-web-api

I need to upload a file to server from a wpf application, the file path would be same always, so it would be simple if web api expected file path only.

But the web api method looks like this:

```
 // POST api/values
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file)
 {
    // Upload logic goes here.
 }
```

So I am not sure how to create an object of type IFormFile from the file path which I have.

Note: IFormFile interface is there in Microsoft.AspNet.Http namespace.

Comment: I presume the IFormFile interface is something developed by who created the Web Method, probably this interface implements some Methods and properties and what you need to do is create a class that implements that interface putting the information of the file you want to load inside the class and passing it to the web method.

Comment: This interface is there in Microsoft.AspNet.Http namespace. I edited my question.

Comment: Ok the answer is the same, you have to create an instance of a class implementing the IFormFile interface (or create a new one) and this interface probably contains the properties to indicate the name of your file, passing then the class to your web method your upload file method should succeed.

Comment: Being curious, I've made a little search on IFormFile interface and I found little to nothing, but what I noticed about it is that anything related to it is Connected to Uploading files using Web Forms (in ASP.Net UI interfaces), so maybe what you are trying to use is not exactly the right thing?

Comment: @Sabrina_cs, yes I am thinking the same, may be web api shouldn't have been exposing a method which expects IFormFile object. That looks purely to be consumed by the web applications.