# post files throught ajax formdata

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, post, multipartform-data

I use below method a post files through ajax, work as usual.

is it possible (allow) to put the files data inside object like method b?
try to find a way organise the request data.

a

```
// client side
var formData = new FormData();    
var fileLength = $('input')[0].files.length;
for (var i = 0; i < fileLength; i++) {
  formData.append("files[]", $('input')[0].files[i]);
}


// server side  nodejs
var file = req.files.file;
// .. use file  move file location or do other things
// { file: 
//  [ { fieldName: 'file[]',
//      originalFilename: '....png',
//      path:'....png',
//      headers: [Object],
//      size: 10854,
//      name: '....png',
//      type: 'image/png' } ] }
```

b

```
// client side   
var formData = new FormData();
var request = {};
request.image = {};
// request.image.description = 'str';
// ...

request.image.files = {};
request.image.files = $('input')[0].files;

var request = JSON.stringify(request);    
formData.append("request", request);

// server side  nodejs
// not working
// cant find the file 
// output request.image.files only get list: [ { '0': {}, length: 1 }, [length]: 1 ]
```

**UPDATE**

thanks for @guest271314 and @user4344980 answer, now I use `FileReader` seems will be work, but now I still have some problem ,

inside `appendFormData()` I commented `var request = JSON.stringify(request);`
once I uncomment then `request` object will become `undefined`.

I did test if I remove `appendRequestDataWithImage()` will be ok.
seems the problem related to  `reader.onload`  I don't know whats wrong? do I miss something?

```
function onclickSubmit() {
    $('.submit').on('click', '.button', function() {
      appendFormDataSubmit();
      // self.global().requestPost(url, appendFormDataSubmit()).then(function(response) {

      // });
    });
  }

function appendFormDataSubmit() {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    appendRequestDataWithoutImage().then(function(result) {
      return appendRequestDataWithImage(result);
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      return appendFormData(result);
    }).then(function(result) {
      console.log(result);
      fulfill(result);
    });
  });
}
```

build object

```
function appendRequestDataWithoutImage() {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    var request = {};
    request.data = {};
    request.data.text = 'text';

    fulfill(request);
  });
}
```

then object add files

```
function appendRequestDataWithImage(request) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    var files = self.el.data.find('.dataContainer .data.userInformation.image .content input')[0].files;
    // console.log(files);
    var file = files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {

      var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
    //   // request.data[file.name] = btoa(binaryString);
      request.data.images = btoa(binaryString);

      fulfill(request);
      console.log('load done');
    }

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  });
}
```

then object append to FormData

```
function appendFormData(request) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    console.log(request);
    // var request = JSON.stringify(request);
    // console.log(request);

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("request", request);

    fulfill(formData);
  });
}
```

Comment: Seems like an unnecessary step to take.  Any specific reason why other that organization?  Your object ends up as a property of formData anyway, right?

Comment: What is purpose of attempting to convert `File` object to `Object`  ? You can assign `File` object as value of a `request.image.files` property, though why where `FormData` returns expected results at server-side ?

Comment: @AaronWagner thanks for reply just try to sort them well, because there is a lot different groups include images and text.

Comment: @guest271314 thanks for reply. I can't understand `assign File object as value of a request.image.files property` can you show me some example code ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @guest271314 send request data looks like  {[ image1: { description: text, file: file }, iimage2: { description: text, file: file }] }

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/29109577?s=1|0.3891#29109577

Comment: @guest271314 is that mean I can use somethin like `var reader = new FileReader(); reader.readAsDataURL(new Blob([file], {
 "type": file.type
}));` to get file information like method a server side   ?

Comment: Yes, have you reviewed `js` at link ?

Comment: @guest271314 please see my update code in question.  I can't find way correct do `promise` with `FileReader` and stuck in callback can't return formdata to submit .

Comment: @user1575921 What is returned from `self.global()` ? Not entirely certain of logic ? Are you posting request before `formData` is defined ? What is purpose of `appendfiles` ? What is `request` and `file` at `self.global().appendfiles(request, file)` ?

Comment: @guest271314 I fix this !!! thanks so much for your help

Comment: @user1575921 You could post and accept your own solution http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax post file with json object make request data like

```
{
  "data": {
    "text": "text",
    "images": binaryString
  }
}
```

base on @guest271314 and @user4344980 response

```
function onclickSubmit() {
    $('.submit').on('click', '.button', function() {
      appendFormDataSubmit();
      // requestPost with appendFormDataSubmit() return
    });
  }

function appendFormDataSubmit() {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    appendRequestDataWithoutImage().then(function(result) {
      return appendRequestDataWithImage(result);
    }).then(function(result) {
      return appendFormData(result);
    }).then(function(result) {
      fulfill(result);
    });
  });
}
```

build object

```
function appendRequestDataWithoutImage() {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    var request = {};
    request.data = {};
    request.data.text = 'text';

    fulfill(request);
  });
}
```

then object add files use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

```
function appendRequestDataWithImage(request) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    var files = self.el.data.find('.dataContainer .data.userInformation.image .content input')[0].files;
    var file = files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
      var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
      request.data.images = btoa(binaryString);

      fulfill(request);
    }

    reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
  });
}
```

then object append to [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData)

```
function appendFormData(request) {
  return new Promise(function (fulfill, reject){
    request = JSON.stringify(request);

    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("request", request);

    fulfill(formData);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for HTML5, it possible now. You can use file API to read users selected file from file input. Then, encode it to Base64 to allow you embed it into JSON.

Example of reading and encoding file to Base64: http://jsfiddle.net/eliseosoto/JHQnk/

```
var handleFileSelect = function(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files;
    var file = files[0];

    if (files && file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(readerEvt) {
            var binaryString = readerEvt.target.result;
            request.image.files[file.name] = btoa(binaryString);
        };

        reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

No. $('input')[0].files doesn't give you which file it is or its contents. It is not allowed for javascript to access local files.

Comment: thanks for reply. why method a can be work? if can't access files what is it post??