# how to upload files to destination folder in php

Tags: php, json, ajax, upload

I am trying to upload files to uploads folder with this code: [Upload multiple image using AJAX, PHP and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery#answer-29109577)

In this post, what is the correct way to upload the files to `uploads` folder

This is what i have but doesn't upload the files:

```
if (isset($_POST["file"])) {
// do php stuff
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "uploads/".$_FILES['file']['name']);
// call `json_encode` on `file` object
$file = json_encode($_POST["file"]);

// return `file` as `json` string
echo $file;
};
```

The php code is in the same file at the top where also the form and drop area is

Answer (score 0):

```
    $target_dir = "uploads/";
    $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
      // return json;
    } else {
        echo $_FILES['userfile']['error']; // only just for debuging
        // return json;
    }
```

Comment: @JackMaessen in else parth use `echo  $_FILES['userfile']['error']` to retrieve a error

Comment: i don't get an error at all. Really don't know how to handle the php code with this example. Is this also correct?: `url: "/echo/json/",`

Answer (score 0):

your php code is coorect but you have to change in your ajax call

var formData = new FormData($("#formId"));

```
  $.ajax({
        url:url,
        method : 'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        data: formData,
        mimeType: "multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success:function(data){
```

}
});