# Uploading file(s) and showing the upload progress at the same time by using jQuery AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I'm trying to upload file(s) and showing the upload progress at the same time by using AJAX. Below is my code:

```
<script>
function pro(obj){
    var file = obj.files;
    $.each(file, function (i,file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            var data = e.target.result;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "upload.php",
                contentType: "application/octet-stream",
                processData: false,
                data : data,
                xhr: function () {
                    var xhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                    xhr.upload.onprogress = function (evt) {
                        console.log(file.name+":"+(evt.loaded/evt.total*100)+"%");
                    };
                    return xhr;
                }
            });
        };
        reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    });
}
</script>

<input type="file" onchange="pro(this)" multiple />
```

The result of my code only showed the upload progress, but didn't upload file(s). How can I do to make the result show the upload progress and also upload file(s) at the same time?

Comment: try setting   `contentType: false,`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/