# Blueimp fileupload progress event... which file does it apply to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, upload, drag-and-drop, jquery-file-upload

I'm setting up a file upload (using https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload).  I want to list all the files that the user drops for upload and give each one a progress bar.  It has an event handler for "progress" for each file being uploaded, but I can't seem to find a way to identify which file the progress is for:

```
$('.uploader').fileupload(
{
    dropZone: $('.upload-drop-zone'),
    dataType: 'json',
    url: uploadUrl,
    progress: function (e, data) 
    {
        // data.files is an array of several files, so I don't know which file this progress event is for???

        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
    }
});


// Later on I use this to start the upload of files
$('.uploader').fileupload('send', { files: myArrayOfFiles });
```

So the file upload starts and the progress event is called properly, but I don't know which file the progress event is for.  Anyone know how to identify the file that the event relates to so I can update the proper progress bar in the file list?

Comment: You can compare the `.size` of the `File` object to `event.total`. See also [Upload multiple image using AJAX, PHP and jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28856729/upload-multiple-image-using-ajax-php-and-jquery/)

Comment: i guess that could work for most situations.  However, it's possible that 2 or more files could be the same size, so it's not ideal.