# Send Multiple images with one JSON request

Tags: php, jquery, json, base64

I was working on building rest API,
Where I want to upload multiple images with one post request.

So here.
I am trying to make an array of base64 string of selected images.
That array is JSON.stringify(images_to_upload) to convert to string.
and send that string as JSON post.
and on server side use json_decode() to decode the string array and save the images.

Is my approach correct?
i am not able to execute JSON.stringify(images_to_upload) as this returns nothing.

is there any better way to handle this?

JAVASCRIPT

```
  $("#UploadImage").click(function(){
    var filesSelected = document.getElementById("filesToUpload").files;
    var images_to_upload = new Array();
    //Loop through each image
    for(var i=0;i<filesSelected.length;i++)
    {
      var fileToLoad = filesSelected[i];
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function(fileLoadedEvent){
        var img_string = fileLoadedEvent.target.result;
        //push base64 string in arrray
        images_to_upload.push(img_string);
      };
      fileReader.readAsDataURL(fileToLoad);
     }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(images_to_upload));  //this doesnt work
    data = {
      "images_data":JSON.stringify(images_to_upload) ,
      };
    url = "http://app.com/api/customer/uploadmultipleimg";
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data:data,
      success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
      },
      failure: function(errMsg) {
         console.log(errMsg);
      }
      });
  });
```

HTML

```
<input type="file" name="filesToUpload" id="filesToUpload" multiple="" accept="image/x-png,image/jpeg">
<input type="submit" value="UploadImage" id="UploadImage" name="submit">
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload multiple image using AJAX, PHP and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28856729/1255289)

Comment: Your code seems to work for me. What are you seeing in the console when you make this call: `console.log(JSON.stringify(images_to_upload));`?

Comment: Did you sort this in the end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be hitting a race condition. I've updated the code to only make the call to the API when the final image has been processed by the `FileReader`. This is reliably showing the array and its contents in the console in my test version.

```
$(document).ready(attach_upload_button_click_handler);

function attach_upload_button_click_handler() {
    $("#UploadImage").click(upload_images);
}

function upload_images() {
    var selected_files = document.getElementById("filesToUpload").files;
    var images_to_upload = new Array();

    for (let i = 0; i < selected_files.length; i++) {

        var fileReader = new FileReader();
        fileReader.onload = function (event) {
            images_to_upload.push(event.target.result);

            if (i == selected_files.length - 1) {
                post_data_to_api(images_to_upload);
            }
        };

        fileReader.readAsDataURL(selected_files[i]);
    }
}

function post_data_to_api(images_to_upload) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(images_to_upload));

    // CALL API
}
```

Comment: this gives base64 of only one image

Comment: @PramitSawant This is that code in JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/adamfeather/xpvt214o/887935. If you check the console you'll see all files in the array.

Comment: thanks  [cptcoathanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2571982/cptcoathanger) :)