# Display progress (circle) while submitting bootstrap form using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have form I am building using bootstrap, and it's submitting data to remote server using $http, but there's a time delay in the middle.

I'd like to know how to implement a progress (circle in the middle of the page) to let the user know the form is being submitted, is there a functionality using Angular UI services? I have searched for that and didn't find. Or should I implement this using bootstrap?

Comment: you could just display a gif image while the request is running.

Comment: you can also have a look at this: https://github.com/jfeigel/ngLoader

Comment: I recommend looking into Angular Material. There's a nice directive just for that: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.progressCircular/directive/mdProgressCircular

Comment: You cannot measure the progress event unless it has a `lengthComputable` property. Check  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent/lengthComputable .... if your are uploading a file in your form submission your could try implementing a progress event listener. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22987941/1055987 for more

Comment: Thanks everyone. I need to support all browsers, so the ng-loader doesn't work for IE (I hope people stop using it and requiring it).  The md-progress-circular looks like what I want, I'll give it a reading and a try and get back to you with any questions

Comment: @manonthemat thanks for the tip, it worked fine, if you can include your comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend looking into Angular Material. There's a nice directive just for that: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/#/api/material.components.progressCircular/directive/mdProgressCircular

*As requested by David Hemsey, this is my previous comment as an answer.*

Answer (score 0):

you can reuse these.. [angular-spinner](https://github.com/urish/angular-spinner) or [angular-sham-spinner](https://github.com/harinair/angular-sham-spinner)

[BLOG](http://lemoncode.net/2013/07/31/angularjs-found-great-solution-to-display-ajax-spinner-loading-widget/) about how the spinner works with angularjs

or if you want to do it yourself...

```
app.directive("spinner", function(){
return: {
restrict: 'E',
scope: {enable:"="},
template: <div class="spinner" ng-show="enable"><img src="content/spinner.gif"></div>
}
});
```

i havent tested the code but directive wont be more complex than this...