# File upload progress bar with jQuery using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: jquery, file-upload, xmlhttprequest

[File upload progress bar with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery)

Comment: This question appears to be just a pointer to another one, and as such is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File upload progress bar with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the upload progress bar feature that I have got to know. Glad, If this helps you.

```
$.ajax({

  xhr: function() {
    var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
        percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
        console.log(percentComplete);
        if (percentComplete === 100) {
        }

      }
    }, false);

    return xhr;
  },
  url: posturlfile,
  type: "POST",
  data: JSON.stringify(fileuploaddata),
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```