# Prevent a user to leave page while a file is uploading

Tags: javascript, file-upload, navigation

I want to prevent a user from leaving my site while their file is being uploaded to my server. So I can send an alert message to a user using this javascript...

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
       return "Your files are not completely uploaded...";
 }
```

The issue I’m having is that after the file upload is complete I don’t want to prevent user navigation. So essentially I want to have the alert message pop up only when the user is trying to leave the site while their file is uploading. I can console.log(“file upload is complete”) when the file is completely uploaded so I know where I should be stopping this event but I’m not sure what the code should look like. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `window.onbeforeunload = null;` should do the trick. Notice also, that a message returned from onbeforeunload handler won't be shown in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Just put a flag and check it in beforeunload, set it to true on upload and to false on finish.

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
       if (prevent_leave) {
           return "Your files are not completely uploaded...";
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check using jQuery form plugin. 
[File upload progress bar with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery)

It provides you to get the percentage of file uploaded and by checking it (whether it has completed or not with 100%) you can show an alert message to user.

Answer (score -1):

I have put this javascript in the function where the user first uploads the file...

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
       var prevent_leave = true;
       if (prevent_leave) {
           return "Your files are not completely uploaded...";
       }
 }
```

then I have put this javascript after the file was completed..

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function() {
       var prevent_leave = false;
       if (prevent_leave) {
           return "Your files are not completely uploaded...";
       }
 }
```

And this works as I expected too. Thanks @jcubic

Comment: Why would you declare those variables? The upper if statement will always result in a true and the lower always with a false.