# How to stop a user from leaving the page during a file upload? (ReactJs 18)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to cause a confirmation popup window to appear if the user reloads the page OR uses the back button while a file is still uploading. Note that it must be for BOTH cases, not just one (but I'm fine if each case needs its own code).

How would I go about doing this? I'm using a class in React (export class  extends React.Component...) so it can't use React functional component hooks.

```
class FileUploadComponent extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    uploadingFile: false,
  };

  static contextType = ConfirmationContext;

  componentDidMount = async () => {
    this.checkForStagedUpdates();
  };

  componentWillUnmount = () => {};

  checkForStagedUpdates = async () => {
    .
    .
    .
  };

  uploadFile = async (file: File) => {
    this.setState({
      uploadingFile: true,
    });

    try {
      await uploadUpdateFile(file);
      this.props.notify({
        type: 'success',
        body: 'File uploaded',
      });
      this.checkForStagedUpdates();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      if (err.message.includes('405')) {
        this.props.notify({ type: 'error', body: 'Invalid file' });
      } else {
        this.props.notify({
          type: 'error',
          body: 'There was a problem uploading the file',
        });
      }
    } finally {
      this.setState({ uploadingFile: false });
    }
  };
.
.
.
}
```

I know I need to use some sort of window event listener, but when I try adding these in componentDidMount, such as,

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function (e) {
    if (uploading) {
         return confirmationMessage;
    }
});
```

they don't trigger when I press the back button, even if I manually set the uploading value to true. Sometimes it works if I reload the page, but this is inconsistent.

I've tried the solutions mentioned in the following, but haven't had any luck yet (they just don't trigger):
[Warn user before leaving web page with unsaved changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7317273/warn-user-before-leaving-web-page-with-unsaved-changes)
[Prevent a user to leave page while a file is uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34004650/prevent-a-user-to-leave-page-while-a-file-is-uploading)

Comment: You should spend a small amount of time looking into web workers, if you spawn a worker you can continue the upload as long as the tab is open,  however if the user closes the tab there is nothing you can do to continue. A combination of warning the user when the tab closes https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10311341/confirmation-before-closing-of-tab-browser and web workers may get the result you're after.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844256/alert-for-unsaved-changes-in-form