# HTTP upload - how do I know it's finished?

Tags: javascript, http, upload

In HTTP protocol, I want let users upload some file(s). I am going to use a Javascript library like jQuery to display a progressbar during this process...

How do I know when the upload has completed? I need to notify another server on this and let it know that the files that were just uploaded can be downloaded now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's trivial: when the on-success callback gets called. The usual problem is getting partial upload information...

Comment: I think this question was asked before, so this may be of help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery

Answer (score 0):

for the upload finished you could just do like [this](http://tutorialzine.com/2011/09/html5-file-upload-jquery-php/) and use ajax to send notification to the other server