# How to add loading progress after Submit button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a submit button to call a function named `mandatoryNotes()`. It is taking a few seconds to load in a new widow. I need to show a gif image and page overlay to block user interaction until the loading is complete.

How can I do that?

```
<div class="em" id="formsubmitbutton">
    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="buttonEm" onClick="mandatoryNotes()">
</div>
```

```js
function mandatoryNotes(){
    var formvalue = "invoiceAttributesDetailsFORM";
    validateInput(document.invoiceAttributesDetailsFORM);
    var queryString;
    if (checkValidation == "true") {

        submitSpecialBidDetails(document.invoiceAttributesDetailsFORM);
        queryString = "&EUAM_SELECTED_FORM=" + formvalue;
        var legendURL = "/EUAM/ADRGateway?jadeAction=MANDATORY_NOTES_ACTION_HANDLER";
        var winData = 'scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,status=yes,width=500,height=500';
        window.open("MandatoryNotes.jsp", "ADDVIEWNOTES",winData);
        window.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File upload progress bar with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

What you are creating is not the expected Javascript approach for any kind of a POST/GET to a server.

You have to use **AJAX** to POST on your "MandatoryNotes.jsp" page. 
That way you have a callback when the AJAX call finishes.

Example of an AJAX Call with jQuery:

```
    function mandatoryNotes(){
        var formvalue = "invoiceAttributesDetailsFORM";
        var queryString = "&EUAM_SELECTED_FORM=" + formvalue;
        var legendURL = "/EUAM/ADRGateway?jadeAction=MANDATORY_NOTES_ACTION_HANDLER";

        validateInput(document.invoiceAttributesDetailsFORM);

        if (checkValidation == "true") {
          submitSpecialBidDetails(document.invoiceAttributesDetailsFORM);

          jQuery.ajax({
            url: "MandatoryNotes.jsp",
            data: queryString,
            success: function(response){
              console.log(response);
            }
          });
        }
}
```

Check this out , it will provide some more info : **[AJAX with jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)**

While you have an AJAX call , you can achieve your goal by simply adding / visible / block an animated image in the DOM when your user presses your submit button and on the "success" of your AJAX Call remove / invisible / none the image.

Adding and Removing the image will be done through Javascript either with plain Javascript using [**innerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) and [**removeChild**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/removeChild) or with jQuery :

```
jQuery('#MY_CONTAINER').append("<div id='AJAXLoader'><img src='myAJAXLoader.gif'></img><div>");
jQuery('#MY_CONTAINER').remove();
```

Same with changing the style of your Gif container :

**With jQuery :**

```
jQuery('#AJAXLoader').css("visibility" , "visible");
jQuery('#AJAXLoader').css("visibility" , "hidden");
```

OR

```
jQuery('#AJAXLoader').css("display" , "block");
jQuery('#AJAXLoader').css("display" , "none");
```

**Plain Javascript**

```
document.getElementById('AJAXLoader').style.visibility = "visible";
document.getElementById('AJAXLoader').style.visibility = "hidden";
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('AJAXLoader').style.display = "block";
document.getElementById('AJAXLoader').style.display = "none";
```