# Progress bar of submitted form ($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, progress-bar

I'm trying to find out how to make a progress bar visualising the progress of the form being submitted. Now I find alot of articles where data is being submitted through AJAX/jQuery to a separate php file where the data is being parsed.

But how do I do this when the action attribute of the form is $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] and the data is being processed with php in the same file. (After the submit button is pressed, the page refreshes.)

Example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']) && !empty($_POST['submit'])){
    // some validation code combined with error_message array here
    // uploading data to server and database here
}
?>

...

<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST" id="aaa" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="text" name="title" id="title" size="55" maxlength="55" required>
    <textarea name="description" id="description" maxlength="155" rows="3" cols="55" required></textarea>
    <input type="file" name="images[]" id="file_input">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" id="file_input">
    <input type="file" name="images[]" id="file_input">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: You need to use AJAX and XHR object. It doesn't matter where submit URL is :). You can initiate refresh manually after the form fire success event.

Comment: `$_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]` method reloads the current page with post data. You need to create another endpoint to submit your data through ajax. Meanwhile your data is loading you can show progress bar.

Comment: The above two comments are incorrect. There are a few awkward ways of doing this without ajax, but they are really just old hacks dating from a time before ajax file uploading was widely supported. All still require the use of javascript in some way - are you trying top support an ancient browser? If not, ajax file upload is the best solution by far

Comment: @Steve I'm not trying to support an ancient browser. I'm just trying to find out how to code it.

Comment: @Steve Do you mean the best solution by far by submitting the data through Ajax to a different php parse file to be able to visualize the progress?

Comment: @Thoaren you dont need to post to a seperate file, thats optional, but you do need to post the file via ajax. For an idea how to capture progress look at the second answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery

Comment: @Steve I'm struggling to capture the formdata to implement in the code you provided through the link you gave me. Also how do I visualize the progress bar combined with that code?

Answer (score 0):

Use this ajax function to call The php script in other page

```
$('#loading_spinner').show();

    $.post('php_page.php',
{pickup:pickup,dropoff:dropoff,km:km},function(data){
        $('#fare').html(data);
         $('#loading_spinner').hide();
    });
```

on php page submit the form and return the data in fare div

set #loadingspinner css to

```
#loading_spinner { display:none; }
```

and use any gif image in img tag to show the spinner

```
<img id="loading_spinner" src="ajax-loader.gif">
```

on submit button use this

```
onclick="javaScriptFunction();"
```

and use that ajax part in javaScriptFunction()

This is the example of calculating KM between two points in google maps