# create progressbar for upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I use this code for upload large file in asp MVC with jquery ajax.

```
@section scripts{

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnUpload').click(function () {
            UploadFile($('#uploadFile')[0].files);
        }
        )
    });
    function UploadFile(TargetFile) {
        // create array to store the buffer chunks
        var FileChunk = [];
        // the file object itself that we will work with
        var file = TargetFile[0];
        // set up other initial vars
        var MaxFileSizeMB = 1;
        var BufferChunkSize = MaxFileSizeMB * (1024 * 1024);
        var ReadBuffer_Size = 1024;
        var FileStreamPos = 0;
        // set the initial chunk length
        var EndPos = BufferChunkSize;
        var Size = file.size;

        // add to the FileChunk array until we get to the end of the file
        while (FileStreamPos < Size) {
            // "slice" the file from the starting position/offset, to  the required length
            FileChunk.push(file.slice(FileStreamPos, EndPos));
            FileStreamPos = EndPos; // jump by the amount read
            EndPos = FileStreamPos + BufferChunkSize; // set next chunk length
        }
        // get total number of "files" we will be sending
        var TotalParts = FileChunk.length;
        var PartCount = 0;
        // loop through, pulling the first item from the array each time and sending it
        while (chunk = FileChunk.shift()) {
            PartCount++;
            // file name convention
            var FilePartName = file.name + ".part_" + PartCount + "." + TotalParts;
            // send the file
            UploadFileChunk(chunk, FilePartName);
        }
    }
    function UploadFileChunk(Chunk, FileName) {
        var FD = new FormData();
        FD.append('file', Chunk, FileName);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Home/UploadFile/',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: FD
        });
    }
</script>
```

I need to create progress bar for this. how can i do this ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File upload progress bar with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery)

Comment: @BrentBoden thanks but how can i match that code with my code ?

Comment: Try using this code uploading your file http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/jzxmro8r/

Comment: @BrentBoden thank you but it not work

Comment: What is the error you are getting and can you show the code you were trying ?

Comment: @BrentBoden it not show me error.

Comment: The code of the fiddle logs to the console of your browser its not creating a progress bar

Comment: @BrentBoden https://jsfiddle.net/furywqpn/

Comment: @BrentBoden i know but not show any thing in console

Comment: why aren't you opening the xhr and sending the data, this should do the trick https://jsfiddle.net/furywqpn/1/

Comment: @BrentBoden 
 
i add that but it not work

Comment: Can you provide a working file upload jsfiddle ?

Comment: @BrentBoden All code ?

Comment: you can also use somthing like this " function ComputeProgress(PartCount, TotalParts){
  console.log("Current progress " + (PartCount/TotalParts * 100)
 }" but thats a bit dirty