# upload progress bar with percentage using only jquery - without using php

Tags: jquery, html

I have been working on a file upload in jquery. My requirement is when I click on upload button after uploading file. I want to display a progress bar in percentage using only jquery. Without using any other server side language like PHP. with out any action php file in form. just upload the file while uploading show progress bar with percentage, no server side actions.

Thanks
Ramu

```
HTML File

<form method="post" id="save_build_upload">

<div class="uploadFileBlock">
               <div class="uploadFile" >
                  <div class="upload-ipa" id="inputFileButton">
                     <i class="sprite ipa-icon "></i>
                     <span>Drag and drop the file or click to upload. </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="outputIPA"></div>
               </div>
               <div class="uploadFile">
                  <div class="upload-apk">
                     <i class="sprite apk-icon "></i>
                     <span>Drag and drop the file or click to upload. </span>
                  </div>
                  <div class="outputAPK"></div>
               </div>
            </div>

<div id='output_image'></div>

<div id="uploadButtonDiv">              
      <button type="submit" class="btn" id="uploadBuildFile" onClick="uploadFile();">Upload</button>                  
</div>

</form>
```

javascript file

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#save_build_upload").submit(function(){

var form_data = new FormData();        
        jQuery.each(jQuery('#inputFile')[0].files, function(i, file) {
            form_data.append('file', file);
            console.log('adding file' + file)          

       });

       event.preventDefault();        

       $.ajax({
                url: '/v1/appManagement/upload/' + localStorage.getItem("userId") + '/',
                data: form_data,
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(data){
                    console.log('File Uploaded!')  
                    window.location.reload();                              
               }
        });

}); //End of submit

});
```

Comment: **without server side language** you can only show progress bar for specific time only

Comment: yes i want to display progress bar for specific time with percentage

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File upload progress bar with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery)

Comment: problem fixed by this reference : http://blog.fraser-hart.co.uk/upload-progress-bar-with-jquery/