# Display progress bar while uploading file to AWS S3 with using Php and Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, amazon-s3

I am using **AWS S3** to store my web application's file like videos and images, the framework of application was **CodeIgniter**.

The flow of my system to upload file is like this:
**AJAX > PHP > AWS**

I can successfully upload the file to a bucket by using Php SDK provided by AWS, but I had a problem while displaying a progress bar.

Using **xhr event listener** to show progress bar is only tracking the upload progress of local server, is not for the AWS S3 upload status. This will become even progress bar is 100% but AWS S3 haven't completed yet.

So my question is **how to track the AWS S3 upload progress percentage and display it at html code?**

I hope can display the progress status like:

***15% of 100% uploaded*** ( << This will live update )

Thanks for all.

```
** Controller **
public function Ajax_uploadmedia()
{
  if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
  {
     if(empty($_FILES['video_attach']['name'])){ echo 'Video File cannot be empty'; exit(); }

     $fileExtension = get_file_ext($_FILES['video_attach']['name']);
     $newfilename = uniqid();
     $config['upload_path']   = UPLOAD_PATH.'/videos/';
     $config['allowed_types'] = 'mp4|mov';
     $config['file_name']      = $newfilename;
     $this->load->library('upload', $config);
     if($this->upload->do_upload('video_attach'))
     {
        $uploadData = $this->upload->data();

        // AWS S3 Upload Process
        $this->load->library('Awslib');
        $objAwsS3Client = $this->awslib->initial();
        $uploadedFilePath =(UPLOAD_PATH.'/videos/'.$uploadData['file_name']);
        $objAwsS3Client->putObject(array(
           'Bucket' => 'gpstudysys',
           'Key'    => 'videos/'.$uploadData['file_name'],
           'Body'   => fopen($uploadedFilePath, 'r'),
           'ACL'    => 'public-read'              
        ));

     }
  }
}
```

**Jquery Ajax Request**

```
  $('#update_media_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

    $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(event) {
                if (event.lengthComputable) {
                    var percentComplete = (event.loaded / event.total)*100;

                    var percentDisplay = Math.round(percentComplete);
                    $('#percent_progress').text(percentDisplay+'%');
                    $('#percent_progress').attr('aria-valuenow', percentDisplay);
                    $('#percent_progress').attr('style', 'width: '+percentDisplay+'%');

                }
           }, false);
           return xhr;
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>url_to/ajax/upload_media',
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData,
        //dataType: 'json',
        complete:function(){
            console.log("Request finished.");
        },
        success: function(response){
            // callback(response);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File upload progress bar with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery)