# how to create file upload progress bar in django?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I am trying to create a video blog where users will be able to upload their videos. I have created view and form to upload the file, and also customized the HTML5 video player followint some tutorials. Now I want add a file uploading progress bar but I can't do it for the shortage of my knowledge in programming. I am trying for the last few days. I have found some very old answers on Stackoverflow but they are very difficult for me to understand. I do not want to use any bootstrap framework because my full demo site has been built without  any 3rd party framework. I am using **Python 3.6**, **Django 2.2.5**, **Postgresql 11** on **Ubuntu 18.04**. 
Guys could you please see my codes bellow and help me with the easiest way to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

**Here is the post form:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<!-- GRID SYTEM BEGINS -->
<main id="content" class="main-area">
    <section class="detail-main-content">
        <div class="all-account">
            <h1>Create a new post</h1>
            <!-- form action should be blank always -->
            <form method="POST" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                <button type="submit">POST</button>
            </form>            
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
{% endblock content %}
```

**Here is the forms.py file:**

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post



class BaseForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')  
        super(BaseForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class BaseModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('label_suffix', '')
        super(BaseModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class PostForm(BaseModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'clip', 'description')

class EmailPostForm(BaseForm):
    your_name = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    to = forms.EmailField()
    description = forms.CharField(required=False,
                               widget=forms.Textarea)
```

**Here is the views.py file:**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect    
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin, UserPassesTestMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,        
    UpdateView,
    DeleteView,   
)    
from . models import Post
from .forms import PostForm, EmailPostForm    


@login_required
def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        # without request.FILES file upload field won't work
        form = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.publish = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post-detail', id=post.id)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'vblog/post_new.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery

Comment: @ToanQuocHo I have tried this solution before but could not work. Thanks for your concern.