# How to show the percentage of the progress bar for saving file

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui

I need to show the progress bar during saving file in aspx page.  it is an internal web app. The user click the link then it can copy the file to their folder within the network. I found the web to create progress bar. I wonder how I know the accurate percentage of saving process to adjust the bar.

I found the website to show the progress bar at
[Animated Progress Bar in 4 lines of jQuery](http://workshop.rs/2012/12/animated-progress-bar-in-4-lines-of-jquery/)

Comment: Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You may also want to include any work you have tried or errors you've encountered.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410265/file-upload-progress-bar-with-jquery